# What happens when there is partial initialization of an array of struct in C?

Tags: c, coding-style

What does this code mean?

```
struct foo_t {
    int a;
    int b;
} foo[10] = {{0,0}}
```

foo[0] is `{0,0}`, but what about the rest? 
How does the C standard handle this?

*ADDED.* I founded an exhaustive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828294/c-and-c-partial-initialization-of-automatic-structure). I think my question should be deleted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C and C++ : Partial initialization of automatic structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828294/c-and-c-partial-initialization-of-automatic-structure)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The entire array will be initialized with structs with the value 0 for both `a` and `b`. This is similar to the following case with a primitive value:

```
int foo[10] = {0};
```

Where every integer in the array will be initialized with the value `0`.

The C99 standard specifies the following:

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>       of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>       size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>       initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

Answer (score 2):

A value of 0 usually means the end of a list. By this I mean that when you iterate such a list and you encounter this value toy know that you have reached the end. I suppose that whoever created this ad something like this in his mind. If you search through the code you might find a fragment of code that sets a zero value after appending a value in the list.

Comment: Sorry for my English. But I mean *how the structure will be initialized*. I'm interesting about language, not how author wants to use the code above. I slightly edited my question.

Comment: Ok here it is. An array like this reserves a block of memory in the data area of the program. The compiler in compile time initialises this memory with 0s. If it is a local variable the global block is copied to the stack in order to initialise it. Remember that this array of structures occupies a consecutive block of memory so by setting all the bytes to 0 you actually initialise the array. I hope I managed to answer you question.