# Init local array with zeros in C++

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C and C++ : Partial initialization of automatic structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828294/c-and-c-partial-initialization-of-automatic-structure)

I'm looking for a fast way to init local array with zeros. (By "Fast", I mean "Fast to type.") When I do the following:

```
HANDLE hHandles[32] = {0};
```

does it zero out the first element or all 32?

Comment: You don't even need to type the zero.  You can just type: `HANDLE hHandles[32] = {};`

Comment: Why don't you type this, compile and run?

Comment: @texasbruce: That wouldn't tell you anything particularly useful with regards to what behavior is mandated by the C++ standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It initializes all the 32 elements to zero.

Comment: Thanks. I just needed to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

See [this surprisingly popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c/201116) for details/alternatives. The difference between C and C++ seems to be that in C++ `{}` will do zero-initialization as well.