# GCC warning for partially initialized array

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, gcc-warning

I know the compiler sets the uninitialized array elements to 0 if the array is partially initialized.

```
int arr[3] = {3,1};
```

But is there a warning option in GCC or similar method to list partially initialized arrays?

Comment: `-Wmissing-field-initializers` might be what you want. All I know is that I use the `no` version with `-Wall` and `-Wextra` because the warning is fairly annoying.

Comment: `-Wmissing-field-initializers` seems to only work with structs, I just tested with an array and no warning :<

Comment: Odd, I was fairly sure I got warnings for arrays before I stuck that on. I guess my reason for taking it out *was* structures, though.

Comment: I'm guessing there is no warning:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828294/c-and-c-partial-initialization-of-automatic-structure

Comment: @Jim ya that sucks :/

Comment: Just to be clear, setting uninitialized array elements to zero (*in this context*) is mandated by the language; it's not just gcc.