# Pointer tracing in C

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

7. What is the output of the following code fragment?

---

```
int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3};
int *p1, *p2;
p1 = arr;
p2 = &arr[3];
printf("%d\n", (*p1)++ + --(*p2));
```

From my understanding, 
The first line initialises an array of 5 memory spaces and only fills positions 0,1 and 2.
Then in the 3rd and 4th line, p1 points to the array position 0 and p2 points to array position 3 which is empty.
So in line 5 when the question tries to print (*p1)++ + --(*p2), what will it print since p2 points to memory not containing any values?

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: _what will it print since p2 points to memory not containing any values?_ garbage (nothing useful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are fewer initializers than array elements, the extra array elements are initialized to zero.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10828333/153430) cites the relevant portion of the C99 standard:

> The C and C++ standards guarantee that even if an integer array is
>   located on automatic storage and if there are fewer initializers in a
>   brace-enclosed list then the uninitialized elements must be
>   initialized to 0.

C99 Standard 6.7.8.21

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in
>   a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
>   are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
>   duration.