# made 2d array using two different sized 1d arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

How can i make a 2d array `arr[][]` using two 1d arrays `arr1[] arr2[]` of different sized,
  like `arr1 = {1,2,3}` `arr2 = {4,5}`and it should looks like:

```
arr[][] = 1 2 3
          4 5
```

Comment: c or c++? why do you use the `pointer` tag? Seems like you have already a solution in mind. If yes, please show your code. If not, forget about pointers and use `std::vector`

Comment: You can't have 2D  array with varied 1D array sizes.

Comment: @machine_1 is that c/c++ specific? because im pretty sure you can in other languages

Comment: @mast3rd3mon  yes, c++ needs array lengths, apart from the first dimension, which is inferred. Other languages "arrays" are actually more like c++'s "vectors".

Comment: seems a bit odd for people to downvote without comment considering this can be done in other languages though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that on C++, the only two ways are pointers or the stl vector, which I would recommend for being easier.
Something like this (using C++11):

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector< vector<int> >arr = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}};
}
```

If you can't use C++11, you can still initialise the vector adding every value inside a loop or one by one using `push_back()`.

Answer (score -1):

You can't have a multidimensional array by using `arr[][]` because you must declare the size of the array in advance. For instance the following is valid, but the array is only [partly initialised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828294/c-and-c-partial-initialization-of-automatic-structure):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int arr[][4] = {
                     { 1, 2, 3 },
                     { 4, 5 },
                     { 6, 7, 8, 9},
                    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << arr[i][j] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Your other alternative is to dynamically declare the array:

```
int* arr[3] {
    new int[4] { 1, 2, 3 },
    new int[2] { 4, 5 },
    new int[4] { 6, 7, 8, 9},
    };
```

You would or course, need a record of array lengths and need to free the memory afterwards!

And this is all assuming you can't use `std:vector`, which would be ideal.

Comment: "_but the array is only partly initialised_" There's no such thing as "partial initialization". It is _fully_ initialized. As in, the array elements that you didn't give the value explicitly, are default-initialized (which is `0` for numeric types).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius true that. For clarity "Partial Initialization is a non-standard terminology which commonly refers a situation where you provide some initializers but not all " - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828294/c-and-c-partial-initialization-of-automatic-structure