# Why does using parenthesis make a multi dimentional array behave like this?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, initialization, comma-operator, braced-init-list

I accidentally covered the numbers with these instead of the curly brackets normally used and got "2 4 0 0". Why does this shifting happen?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a[2][2]={(1,2),(3,4)};
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        /* code */
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
        {
            /* code */
            printf("%d ",a[i][j] );
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do

Comment: C has the infamous "comma operator", so when `( a, b )` is evaluated it returns `b`.

Answer (score 1):

In the braces of the list initialization in this declaration

```
int a[2][2]={(1,2),(3,4)};
```

there are present two expressions `( 1, 2 )` and `( 3, 4 )`. They are primary expressions with the comma operator.

According to the C Standard (6.5.17 Comma operator)

> 2 The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void
> expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that
> of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result
> has its type and value

So the values of the expressions are `2` and `4`.

Thus in fact you have

```
int a[2][2]={ 2, 4 };
```

As a result the first sub-array of the array that is the array a[0] is initialized with these values. Elements of the second sub array a[1] are zero initialized.

If for example you would write

```
int a[2][2]={(1,2,3,4)};
```

then this declaration is equivalent to

```
int a[2][2]={ 4 };
```

and only the element `a[0][0]` will be explicitly initialized by the value `4`,

Another example of using an expression with the comma operator as an initializer.

```
int i = 0;
int j = ( i++, i++, i++ );
```

As a result `i` will be equal to `3` and `j` to `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally used the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). In your case it did nothing, but the resulting value from it is the last value in the comma separated list: `(1,2)` results in the last value `2` and `(3,4)` results in `4`.

So your code was equivalent to:

```c
int a[2][2]={2,4};
```

The last two of the four values in `a` were not provided, so they were initialized implicitly with zeroes. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828294/c-and-c-partial-initialization-of-automatic-structure) explains exactly why.