# Initializing local array variable in C

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, storage-duration

Is it guaranteed that first element in the below array will be set to `1` and all others to `0`, or is it compiler defined behavior?

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main () {
    uint16_t arr[10] = {1};
}
```

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828294/c-and-c-partial-initialization-of-automatic-structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 19 The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each
> initializer provided for a particular subobject overriding any
> previously listed initializer for the same subobject;154) **all
> subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized
> implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.**

and

> 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
> explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static
> or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or
> unsigned) zero;
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively)
> according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized
> (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized
> to zero bits;

So as the element type of your array is an arithmetic type then all elements of the array except the first element that has an explicit initializer will be zero-initialized.

Pay attention to that according to the C standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```