# Why `throw MyClass' doesn't work and `throw MyClass()' does?

Tags: c++, exception

I read somewhere (cannot find the source now) that

```
MyClass *p1 = new MyClass;
```

and

```
MyClass *p2 = new MyClass();
```

are essentially equivalent, provided that `MyClass` provides a default constructor. The compiler understands what I want to do and adds the empty parentheses.

If this is the case, why I am not allowed to write

```
throw MyException;
```

but have to use

```
throw MyException();
```

? (Yep, a question mark at the beginning of a line.)

To add some more confusion, the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/empty-parens-in-object-decl.html) suggests that the second usecase (`new MyClass()`) does not invoke a constructor, but calls function defined with `operator()` instead.

Comment: An interesting quirk in C++: You cannot have value-initialized automatic objects, and you cannot have default-initialized temporary objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The compiler understands what I want to do and adds the empty parentheses.

No it doesn't; the two expressions aren't quite equivalent. The difference is in how the objects are are initialised: the first uses default-initialisation, while the second uses value-initialisation. So they are equivalent for classes that define a default constructor; otherwise, the first will leave POD objects uninitialised, while the second will initialise them to zero.

> why I am not allowed to write `throw MyException;`?

`MyException()` is an expression that creates a value-initialised temporary object; you can throw that just like you can throw the value of any other suitable expression.

`MyException` isn't an expression; it's just a type name. You can only throw the value of an expression, so `throw MyException;` is not valid. There's no way to create a default-initialised temporary.

> To add some more confusion, the C++ FAQ suggests that the second usecase (new MyClass()) does not invoke a constructor, but calls function defined with operator() instead.

No it doesn't. It says that a declaration like `List x();` declares a function with a return type `List`, not (as one might think) a value-initialised object of type `List`. It has nothing to do with new-expressions or `operator()`.

Comment: To make sure that I understand properly: _"the first uses default-initialisation, while the second uses value-initialisation."_ This means that the first one calls the default constructor, whereas the second one creates a temporary object and uses the assignment operator?

Comment: @peter.slizik: No. If the class has a non-trivial default constructor, then both will use that. If it doesn't, then default-initialisation will leave POD objects uninitialised, while value-initialisation will initialise them to zero values. Neither will create a temporary or use assignment.

Comment: @peter.slizik: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341) for more details about the various types of initialisation in C++.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I never heard of the distinction. The reason is probably here: _One thing to realize is that 'value-initialization' is new with the C++ 2003 standard - it doesn't exist in the original 1998 standard._

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not throwing `new` exception, but rather constructing it.

Consider following:

```
MyException exception = MyException(); // works
MyException exception = MyException; // doesn't work

new MyException; // works
new MyException();// works
```

Answer (score 0):

The situation listed in the FAQ is different and doesn't apply here.

`MyException` is just a type name in the first case, and creates a variable in the second. That's just the syntax. Same as

```
MyException ex = MyException;
```

wouldn't compile, but

```
MyException ex = MyException();
```

would. The FAQ example illustrates simply the equivalent of:

```
MyException ex();
```

which would indeed be a function declaration, whereas:

```
MyException ex;
```

would.

There's no way that

```
throw MyException();
```

or

```
MyException ex = MyException();
```

could be interpreted as a function declaration, so they work.