# Compiler generated default constructor working - C++

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I am trying to learn about the default constructor working of class and am not able to figure out this situation:

Case 1:

```
class A  
{  
  public:
     int m;
     string s;
};
```

Then I create object of this class:
a) `A a; // Result: compiler initializing m with garbage value`
b) `A a = A(); // Result : compiler initializing m with garbage value`

Case 2: Now I removed string `s` from my class:

```
class A
{
  public:
    int m;
};
```

a) `A a; // Result: when try to access m I get run time error`
b) `A a = A(); //Result: m is initialized to zero`

Q1) Why there is discrepancy in case 1 and case 2?
Q2) What if I provide default constructor to my class in both cases then a) & b) will be same?

Comment: 2.a feels strange, `m` should be uninitialized, but shouldn't give you a runtime error...

Comment: I agree.  No idea why that would give a runtime error.

Comment: @Matteo Italia: Yes that is the main reason of asking this question ...I dont know why I am getting run time error.

Comment: That runtime error may be kind of a debugging assertion (usage of uninitialized variable...) like the one MSVC generates. This would vanish in a release build. The default constructor basically just calls the default constructor of all members. That int, as all other primitive types, has no such constructor. And if the constructor does nothing, it might gets optimized away anyway.

Comment: Yes thats the one I am getting is it compiler dependent ?

Comment: Yes, that is MSC debugging stuff, enabled by /RTCsu (see C/C++ code generation settings in project properties). I'd leave this enabled as it helps to fix constructors and initialization in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1: Class `A` is a non POD.
Case 2: Class `A` is a POD.

```
a) A a; //This is default initialization
b) A a = A(); // This is value initialization
```

Case '1': `m` will be initialized to some garbage value by the compiler generated default constructor.

Case '2': `m` will be zero initialized because `A` is a POD.

You should not be getting a crash in any of the scenarios. If you do probably you are using a broken compiler.

For more details on default initialization and value initialization refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializat).

Answer (score 3):

Because in both cases, the integer is uninitialized.  That means its value is undefined.  It could be zero, or any other value an integer can hold.

If you want to initialise it to zero in the default constructor, you can do it like this:

```
class A
{
  public:
    A::A();
    int m;
};

A::A()
  : m( 0 )
{}
```

Note that you don't have to provide an explicit constructor for a `string` because it is a class, and has its own default constructor.

Comment: Creating object like A a = A(); does it guarantees that int will be initialized to zero ??(If I dnt give def ctor)

Answer (score 0):

The only difference of `class A` between case 1 and case 2 is that in case 1 the compiler will sythenize a [non-trivial default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Trivial_default_constructor) because `s` in `class A` is a non-primitive type.
However, in both cases, the `m` is not being initialized.