# Getting constant empty line output when retrieving a string from a pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

This is making me think I'm not using the pointer correctly.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "room.h"

void initializeRooms(std::vector<Room*>& rooms);

int main() {
  std::vector<Room*> rooms;
  initializeRooms(rooms);
  Room* r = rooms[0];
  std::cout << "You are in room " << r->getName() << "\n";
  return 0;
}

void initializeRooms(std::vector<Room*>& rooms) {
  Room roomOne {"roomOne"};
  Room roomTwo {"roomTwo"};
  Exit exit { &roomOne, &roomTwo };
  roomOne.addExit(&exit);
  rooms.push_back(&roomOne);
  rooms.push_back(&roomTwo);
}
```

exit.cpp

```
class Room;

struct Exit {
  Room* room_one;
  Room* room_two;
};
```

room.h

```
#ifndef ROOM_H
#define ROOM_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "exit.cpp"

class Room {
private:
  std::string name;
  std::vector<Exit*> exits;

public:
  Room(std::string n): name{n} {

  }

  void addExit(Exit* e);
  std::string& getName();
};

#endif
```

room.cpp

```
#include "room.h"

void Room::addExit(Exit* e) {
  exits.push_back(e);
}

std::string& Room::getName() {
  return name;
}
```

So in the main file, when the cout is called, I just see a constant loop of empty lines being output when i run the compiled file. Just keeping it simple now and using a makefile with clang

```
all: build

build: main.o exit.o room.o
    clang++ -std=c++11 main.o exit.o room.o -o simplegame

main.o: main.cpp
    clang++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp

exit.o: exit.cpp
    clang++ -std=c++11 -c exit.cpp

room.o: room.cpp
    clang++ -std=c++11 -c room.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *o simplegame
```

Comment: `roomOne`, `roomTwo` and `exit` are local to `initializeRooms`. You are pushing pointers to the first two into a vector that lives beyond the scope of the function, leaving it with dangling pointers and leading to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Also note the typo in Room constructor, should be `name(n)`

Comment: @Leeor That syntax is fine I believe for C++11 (and in some cases preferred).  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18222927/1843316

Comment: Ok, thanks. Please retag, i was assuming standard c++ (didn't notice the makefile args)

Comment: I'm not baring anything with you. Nothing personal, but you're not my type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting aside that you should not use raw pointers unless you fully understand what you are doing, following code have the problem:

```
void initializeRooms(std::vector<Room*>& rooms) {
  Room roomOne {"roomOne"};    // this is local object
  Room roomTwo {"roomTwo"};    // this is local object as well 
  Exit exit { &roomOne, &roomTwo }; // exit is also local object and now it holds pointers to other 2 local objects
  roomOne.addExit(&exit);  // same stuff as before
  rooms.push_back(&roomOne); // now you are inserting pointer to local object into vector
  rooms.push_back(&roomTwo); // doing that again
} // now all local objects to this function automatically destroyed and you hold pointers to garbage in rooms
```

So instead of using local objects you need to create them on the heap. 
As I said before I would also recommend to use shared_ptr and weak_ptr (later is neccessary because you have cyclic reference).

Comment: Good to know thank you. Just been going through the 4th edition of The C++ Programming language, been trying to implement some basics to better have it sunk in. Haven't really gotten to much on the shared_ptr, unique_ptr and weak_ptr yet.

Comment: @agmcleod: There is completely no need for you to use raw pointers in this demo. `std::vector` holds value, so you can just `push_back` the `Room` created into it. Or better `emplace_back`.