# function returning nullptr with no return

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

On Overload Jouranl for this month I found an article about how to design Observer pattern with C++11. You'll find it [here](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/2040). The reading is interesting but I found a piece of code using `std::atomic` I don't really understand.

What is the meaning of function `next` below? It doesn't even seem a function declaration (no `return` keyword). I am using `g++ 4.7.2`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <atomic>

struct ListItem {
 ListItem() {}
 ...
 atomic<ListItem*> next{nullptr};
 ~ListItem() { delete next.load(); }
 };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't a function but a member declaration with a *non-static data member initializer*.

```
atomic<ListItem*> next{nullptr};
```

In a constructor that does not initialize `next`, `next` will automatically be initialized with `nullptr`. The initialization is done via [list-initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives) which was introduced in C++11 (together with non-static data member initializers - the latter partly depends on the former).

GCC 4.7.x [should support this](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/cxx0x_status.html).

Comment: For OP's benefit: Specifically, it uses the new C++11 *universal initialization* syntax, which uses braces (`{}`) instead of parens.

Comment: @cdhowie It cannot use parentheses anyway.

Comment: I know, but that's not the point. OP may not be familiar with this new C++11 syntax, so I'm putting a name to it.

Comment: @cdhowie I know that it's not the point. :o) (I'll adjust the answer in a second)

Comment: @cdhowie: The name is *list-initialization*, not "universal initialization".