# Delegating constructors in c++ () or {}

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, delegation

I read [this link](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#delegating-ctor) of Stroustrup with the following code:

```
class X {
        int a;
    public:
        X(int x) { if (0<x && x<=max) a=x; else throw bad_X(x); }
        X() :X{42} { }
        X(string s) :X{lexical_cast<int>(s)} { }
        // ...
    };
```

My question is about the line:

`X() X{42}{}`

Is there any differences between parentheses and curly brackets?
 If there is no differences can I use curly brackets in other function calls as well? Or is it just in constructor delegation?
And at last Why we should have both syntaxes? It is a little ambigous.

Comment: "can I use curly brackets in othere functions calls as well or is it just in constructor delegation?" — Constructor delegation is not a function call. You can never use `{}` with function calls.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`()` uses [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) if the parentheses are empty, or [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) if non-empty.

`{}` uses [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), which implies [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) if the braces are empty, or [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) if the initialized object is an aggregate.

Since your `X` is a simple `int`, there's no difference between initializing it with `()` or `{}`.

Comment: If I understand right it means if I am wrinting `X(): X(42){}` then I am calling the inte constructor but if I am writing the `X(): X{42}{}` then I am just initializing memebr variables without calling another constructor?

Comment: @Govan - primitive types such as `int` and `double` aren't full-fledged objects. They don't have constructors.

Comment: @DavidHammen I meant X(int constructor) not primitive int constructior

Comment: @Govan Since `int` has no constructor there is no constructor to be called while initializing `X`. Both `X(42)` and `X{42}` will perform the direct initialization, and since `X` is of type `int`, that means an implicit conversion from `42` to `int` will be performed to initialize `X`. So in the case of a simple `int`, both `()` and `{}` do the same thing.

Comment: "Since X is of type `int`" - no it isn't!  It's a fully fledged class.  Admittedly it only has one data member of type `int`, but it has *three* user-defined constructors.

Answer (score 6):

Initialization values can be specified with parentheses or braces.

Braces initialization was introduced with C++11 and it is meant to be "uniform initialization" that can be used for all non-static variables.

Braces can be used in the place of parentheses or the equal sign and were introduced to increase uniformity and reduce confusion.

It is only a syntactical construct and does not result in performance benefits or penalties.