# Uniform Initialization In Template Code

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++4.8, uniform-initialization

To the best of my understanding, [uniform initialization](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#uniform-init) is the preferred syntax for initializing objects. Herb Sutter [writes](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/)

> For one thing, it’s called “uniform initialization” because it’s, well, uniform—the same for all types, including aggregate structs and arrays and std:: containers...

and the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives) states

> Prefer {} initialization over alternatives unless you have a strong reason not to.

However, consider this code:

```
#define BRACES                                                                                                                                                                                           

template<typename V>
class foo {   
public:
    template<typename W>
    explicit foo(const W &w) : 
#ifdef BRACES
        m_v{w}
#else // #ifdef BRACES
        m_v(w)
#endif // #ifdef BRACES
    {}  

private:
    V m_v;
};  

struct bar{};  

int main() 
{   
    bar b;

    foo<bar>{b};
#ifdef BRACES
    bar c{b};
#else // #ifdef BRACES
    bar c(b);
#endif // #ifdef BRACES                                                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

If `#define BRACES` is uncommented, this code fails to build (g++ 4.8.5) with `error: too many initializers for ‘bar’` on the line

```
    m_v{w}
```

in the constructor of `foo`. This makes sense, as the more direct invocation

```
 bar c{b};
```

in `main` fails similarly, and they are essentially the same (although the template code does not know that).

Conversely, commenting `#define BRACES` causes everything to build. Is this an indication to avoid this form of initialization in this type of template code?

**Edit**

@melak47 pointed out that this problem does not appear in g++5.1, and gave [convincing proof](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b4cc7882c29e485). It apparently disappeared somewhere between 4.8.5 and 5.1.

Comment: I think this is an indication to upgrade your compiler to GCC >= 5.1.

Comment: @melak47 If you can verify that this works with 5.1, then it is a fine answer, and feel free to write it as such.

Comment: [See for yourself](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b4cc7882c29e485) :)

Comment: @melak47 :-) OK, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

List-initialization didn't quite work when you attempt to initialize an aggregate from something of the same type.

This is [CWG 1467](http://wg21.link/cwg1467), whose resolution (among other things) introduced another bullet to the giant list in [[dcl.init.list]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3) to make this work:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined
>   as follows:
>
> - If `T` is a class type and the initializer list has a single element of type *cv* `U`, where `U` is `T` or a class derived from `T`, the
>     object is initialized from that element (by copy-initialization for
>     copy-list-initialization, or by direct-initialization for
>     direct-list-initialization).

Comment: Many thanks. IIUC, then, it should change in a later implementations of later versions of the standards?

Answer (score -1):

When the overloaded constructor is resolved, braced initialization will match a constructor using std::initializer_list parameters, before considering other overloaded constructors. So

```
bar c{b};
```

will match to a constructor taking std::initializer_list, rather than the generated copy constructor.

This is discussed in Item 7: *Distinguish between () and {} when creating objects* of Scott Meyers - Effective Modern C++.

Also, [Wikipedia - C++11 Uniform initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization)

Comment: But `bar` has no constructor taking a `std::initializer_list`

Comment: @AndrewDuncan I agree with melak47  - sorry, but I just don't see how this addresses the question. Many thanks, though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will put more thought answers I give in the future.

Comment: @AndrewDuncan Feel free to delete the answer if you want - just a tip.