# What is the difference between initializing variables with {} instead of ()

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I've been watching lots of CppCon lectures and I've noticed that Bjarne and Herb both initialize things like this
`std::unique_ptr<foo>{bar}` instead of `std::unique_ptr<foo>(bar)`.

Is there a difference between them that could make them prefer the former?

Comment: List initialization does not allow narrowing (§iso.8.5.4). More explanations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives