# float initialization from double with braces

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, list-initialization, value-initialization

Why does the compiler (clang,gcc) not warn about narrowing conversions when doing this

```
float a{3.1231231241234123512354123512341235123541235};
float a = {double(3.1231231241234123512354123512341235123541235)}
```

I expected a warning because I do explicit value-initialization with braces.
Following this answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18222927/293195) it should spit out an error.

[Compilation here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13e474d1b598b4f5)

Comment: afaik, it does not warn you if a particular literal value can be represented in a narrower type without precision loss

Comment: This doesn't compile on VS2015 (error 2397)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[[dcl.init.list]/§7](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#7) (standard draft)

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>
> ...
>
> - from long double to double or float, or from double to float, **except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion is within the range of values that can be represented (even if it cannot be represented exactly)**, or
>
> ...

Both expressions `3.14159` and `double(3.141)` are constant expressions and the value is within the range of values representable by `float`. Therefore the conversion isn't *narrowing* as defined by the standard and there is no requirement to warn about the conversion.

---

> but it does not give a warning also for longer inputs

[Sure it does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb05355672ef18d1), as long as the value is outside of the range of values representable by `float`.

Answer (score 10):

Because the source is a constant expression and overflow does not occur for these cases, then [narrowing conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Narrowing_conversions) error won't be triggered.

(emphasis mine)

> conversion from a long double to double or to float and conversion from double to float, **except where the source is a constant expression and overflow does not occur**

If you use it with a `double` variable(i.e. a non-constant-expression) or a constant with big value which causes overlow, the diagnostic message will be generated. e.g.

```
double d = 3.14159;
float a {d}; // non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'double' to 'float' in initializer list
```

**EDIT** (for longer input)

Because even if the value cannot be represented exactly by `float`, overflow still doesn't occur, then it's allowed.

[$8.6.4/7.2 List-initialization](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#7.2)
(emphasie mine)

> from long double to double or float, or from double to float, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion is within the range of values that can be represented (**even if it cannot be represented exactly**), or

Comment: When you say **should be an error, not a warning**, I would clarify that the standard does not require that be an error.

Comment: @user2079303 The standard says "such conversions are not allowed", so I think warning is not the case, isn't it?

Comment: your are right but it does not give a warning also for longer inputs

Comment: @songyuanyao the standard says "If a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is **ill-formed**". Elsewhere in the standard it says that compiler is required to show a diagnostic message if the program is ill-formed. No other requirements such as the message being an error and preventing compilation.

Comment: @Gabriel See my edited answer, (if I got your point correctly).

Comment: @user2079303 But #7 says "not allowed" explicitly, do you mean such description in the stardard still doesn't mean it should be error, I mean the compilation should fail for this case.

Comment: @songyuanyao The note in #7 begins with "As indicated above" which refers to the rule that I quoted. I would consider it merely a reminder of the rule, rather than an overriding rule. That said, I don't think it makes any difference. I don't think the standard at any point requires that compilation must fail. When a program violates the standard, it is ill-formed (unless specified otherwise such as when there is UB instead) and there must be a message. Whether the message is an error is never specified by the standard and it is at the discretion of the compiler to allow the compilation or not.