# Benefits of std::initializer_list in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I wondered what are the benefits of using `std::initializer_list` , and what purpose does it serve.

I encountered the following: [Why is list initialization (using curly braces) better than the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives)

and understood that the "non-narrowing" effect, although I can't really see how beneficial it is.

Another benefit I can spot, is the relative ease of use when initializing ( for example when initializing a class with several members ), but besides that I don't see any major improvement, which really makes initialization using initializer_list a good practice, especially in terms of efficiency.

Comment: So your question is actually *Why is the "non-narrowing" effect of std::initializer_list beneficial*?

Comment: Indeed, and any other benefit which perhaps I don't know of, is most welcome.

Comment: I think that would be two different questions. The first would probably be sufficiently specific. The second one, however, would be strange and may closed as a duplicate. After all, that other question has a lot of answers with *many, many* benefits explained, so what more would you expect?

Comment: I don't think performance was a major reason, but ease of use and avoiding common bugs like narrowing conversions and [the most vexing parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work).

Comment: In case the initializer_list provides a vast range of benefits, then this question really should be closed and I should hit the books, and an explanation for the benefits of the non-narrowing effect will be suffice in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most practical purposes, `std::initializer_list` gives one benefit: the ability to initialize objects of arbitrary type.

Lack of narrowing is nice, but absolutely *pales* by comparison to simple convenience of being able to type something like:

```
std::vector<int> foo { 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

rather than:

```
std::vector<int> foo;
foo.push_back(1);
foo.push_back(2);
foo.push_back(3);
foo.push_back(4);
```

...or the multitude of hacks that spawned, mostly based around abusing overloading of the comma operator to get syntax like:

```
std::vector<int> foo;
foo += (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Yes, this can have some tangible benefits in terms of speed (for one example) since the vector will pre-allocate space to prevent reallocation during the initialization from the `initializer_list`. This is clearly a good thing--but being at all honest, it's rarely a deal-maker. If the  intializer_list were more convenient but likely to be slower by some small percentage, people would use it anyway (and quite rightly so, in most cases).