# Who knows which feature of C++ below code is?

Tags: c++

Recently, I saw below code snippet in a project. I can't paste the project code directly but write a similar one instead. I can't understand why "fun(A{a});"
 can pass the compilation and works:(. Does anyone know such C++ feature? What does "**A{a}**" mean?
Thanks very much!

```
class A {
public:
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;
};

void fun(A a) {
    cout << "A.x = " << a.x << endl;
    cout << "A.y = " << a.y << endl;
}

int main() {
    A a;
    fun(A{a});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe that's list initialization. More information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply:). At the beginning, I also thought it should be list initialization. But I still can't find any evidence that says that we can put the class name in front of the "{}". I also made a test. I added the list initializer constructor into the class. But unfortunately, it wasn't invoked. So I rose this question.

Comment: That's a curly braces initializer, syntax introduced in C++11. C++03 had no way to directly initialize a temporary POD. One had to resort to silly factory functions. This particular example copy constructs the temporary.

Comment: My confusion is "Can we put the class name in front of the curly braces?". Is there any official explanation for this syntax?

Comment: see [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Comment: Great thanks, guys! especially for @slawekwin. And I found a more direct explanation from this link http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Comment: @Alex.Liu why don't you write an answer summing up what you found?

Comment: @slawekwin. No problem. Thanks for the kindly reminder:)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for everyone's help, especially for @slawekwin!:) I finally find the answer.

`T { arg1, arg2, ... };` is a kind of list initialization, which creates an unnamed temporary. 
for more information, please refer to this [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

Comment: you could also accept it so the question has its closure :)