# In C++, can we use { } for C-Style casting?

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, explicit-conversion

While I have been reading about datatype conversion, I saw this example:

```
void intval()
{
    for (char c; cin >> c; )
    cout << "the value of '" << c << "' is " << int{c} << '\n';
}
```

I know that we can cast using:

1. `int(c)`
2. `(int) c`
3. `static_cast<int>(c)`

My questions:

Q1: Is `int{c}` another way of casting data types?

Q2: After some research on the net, I know that C++ casting is different and it have the compiler check the casting possibility at the compile time, but what are the differences between 1 and 2? And how `int{c}` is different if it is just another casting way?

Q3: Are there any other ways to explicitly convert/cast?

Comment: I thought that the curly braces were to do with list initialization, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18222927/3110529

TL;DR: List initialization does not allow narrowing (§iso.8.5.4) meaning that it will catch unsafe type conversions.

Comment: In particular, if `d` is a `double` and `double` is the same size as `uint64_t`, `static_cast<uint64_t>(d)` and `reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(d)` convert in completely different ways.  C-style casts don't have that flexibility; you would need to type-pun through a union or pointer to reinterpret the bits.

Comment: @Davislor Since when is `reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>` a thing?

Comment: @curiousguy You’re correct: the proper syntax would be to `reinterpret_cast` to a *reference*, `uint64_t&`. This has been legal (but unspecified) since, I believe, C++03.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is `int{c}` another way of casting data types?

Yes.  `T{value}` creates a temporary of type `T` that is *direct-list-initialized* with the specified *braced-init-list*.  This cast does have an advantage over `T(value)` in that `T{value}` can be used to create a temporary array.  That would be done like

```
int main() {
    using int_array = int[5];
    for( auto e : int_array{1,2,3,4,5})
        std::cout << e;
}
```

It also comes with the caveat that a narrowing conversion is a error

```
int main() {
    int(10000000000ll);  // warning only, still compiles
    int{10000000000ll};  // hard error mandated by the standard
}
```

> After some research on the net, I know that C++ casting is different and it have the compiler check the casting possibility at the compile time, but what are the differences between 1 and 2?

The big difference between `T(value)` and `(T)value` is that in `T(value)`, `T` must be a single word.  For example

```
int main() {
    unsigned int(10000000); // error
    (unsigned int)10000000; // compiles
}
```

> Q3: Are there any other ways to explicitly convert/cast?

Well in C++ they want you to use the C++ casts which are `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, and `const_cast`.  Those are preferred over c style cast as a c style cast will do all of those where the C++ versions have certain limitations and come with certain guarantees.

Answer (score 10):

[`int(c)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) is the  the C++ version of the C-style cast `(int)c`. It first attempts a [`const_cast<int>(c)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast), then (failing that) a [`static_cast<int>(c)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) followed by [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast).

[`int{c}`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) is a slightly different kettle of fish. Strictly, this is list initialization and has more stringent rules. In particular, narrowing conversions are not allowed, i.e.

```
int x;
char s{x};  // error
```

Therefore, it is recommended to use this (rather than casts) unless you know that narrowing conversions are acceptable.

For other than builtin types, there is, in addition to the casts mentioned above, also [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).

Answer (score 4):

Q1: Yes.  It is almost the same as a functional style cast (`int(c)`), and works because of c++11's [uniform initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).  However brace initialization does have a few caveats, for example narrowing conversions (like `long l = 5; char c{l};`) will generate a warning.

Q2: 1 and 2 are equivalent, although there are some situations where one works and not the other.

```
// long long(c); // Breaks unless you make a typedef for 'long long'
(long long)c;    // Works fine

template <class In, class Out>
Out convert(const In& in) {
    // return (Out)in; // Only works if 'In' is a primitive type
    return Out(in);    // Works regardless of the type of 'In' (assuming an appropriate constructor exists)
}
```

Q3: The only example of C++-style casting that you mention is `static_cast`.  There are other C++ casts as well:

- `dynamic_cast`
- `reinterpret_cast`
- `const_cast`

Comment: " (like long l = 5; char c{l};) will generate a warning." I think it should generate a compile error.