# priority_queue in c++ with custom comparator

Tags: c++

I created a priority_queue and define a custom comparator(a struct) which takes an 2D vector in the constructor. It compiles and runs successfully to the point of declaring that priority queue. However, if I try to add an element into the priority queue, it pops me error:

**error: request for member 'push' in 'minHeap', which is of non-class type 'std::priority_queue, std::vector >, MyComparator>(MyComparator)'
     minHeap.push(make_pair(0, 1));**

I would like to know what is the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;



struct MyComparator{
    vector<vector<int>> array2D;

    MyComparator(const vector<vector<int>>& arrays){
        array2D = arrays;   
    }

    bool operator()(const pair<int, int> &p1, const pair<int, int> &p2){
        return array2D[p1.second][p1.first] > array2D[p2.second][p2.first];
    }
};


int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> arrays = {{1, 3, 5, 7}, {2, 4, 6},{0, 8, 9, 10, 11}};
    priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, MyComparator> minHeap(MyComparator(arrays));
```

//work well without error above

```
    minHeap.push(make_pair(0, 1)); //pop me error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is known as the most vexing parse.

```
priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, MyComparator> minHeap(MyComparator(arrays));
```

Here, the compiler cannot decide if this is a function signature or the invocation of a constructor. The usual way to get rid of this ambiguity is by adding a pair of extra parentheses:

```
priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, MyComparator> minHeap((MyComparator(arrays)));
```

Curious's answer is also correct, but there are different takes on using braces for constructor invocation.

Comment: This works! I have never met this kind of problem, but now I know. Thank you! I am happy that I learnt something!!

Answer (score 3):

This is because your priority queue initialization is being treated as a function declaration and not a variable declaration.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse for reasons as to why.

Change the line where you initialize your priority queue to this

```
priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, MyComparator> minHeap{MyComparator(arrays)};
```

and it should work fine.

The reason it works now is because the `{}` is not ambiguous anymore.  The `{}` was introduced in C++11 as a way to construct objects, it is in many cases preferable to parentheses to initialize a variable.  For more see [Why is list initialization (using curly braces) better than the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives)

**Note** For the future, always remember to compile with the warning flags enabled.  The usual recommended ones are `-Werror`, `-Wall` and `-pedantic`.  When you enable those flags, the compiler will alert you to the ambiguity (the most vexing parse) present in your code.

Comment: This should work. If not, try uniform initialization for both `minHeap` and the unnamed `MyComparator` and see:

`priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, MyComparator> minHeap{MyComparator{arrays}};`