# What is the difference between C c(3); and C c{3}; when instantiating a class?

Tags: c++, initialization

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class C{
    public: int a;
    public: C (int i){a = i ; }

};
int main()
{
    C c(3); // C c{3};
    cout<<c.a;
    return 0;
}
```

What is the difference between `C c(3);` and `C c{3};`? They seem to work the same as invoking the constructor.

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't a canonical duplicate for this...

Answer (score 4):

There are two differences:

1. The brace-initialization syntax (assuming the list is nonempty) can call an `std::initializer_list<T>` constructor, and will always do so if possible. The parenthesis syntax will not call an `std::initializer_list<T>` constructor.
2. The brace-initialization syntax prohibits narrowing conversions.

In your example there is no difference, but:

1. If `C` had a constructor taking `std::initializer_list<int>` then `C{3}` would call that constructor while `C(3)` would call the one that takes `int`.
2. `C{3.14}` will not compile since the conversion is narrowing, but `C(3.14)`  will.

Comment: Thanks. May i ask which style of  `C c(3)` and `C c{3}` is more popular in other languages with OO? Is it correct that Java and C# don't have either?

Comment: C# and Java have constructors that are almost the same as `C(int i)`, only with the caveat that they do check for the type being passed in. `new C(3.14)` would fail to compile. There is no support for the `{}` syntax, though. In C#, `new C { a = 3 }` is an object initializer, and you must assign member variables within the `{}`.

Comment: Your first Statement 1 is untrue in general: aggregate initialization is highest priority; then value-initialization for an empty list. Then there is the case where `C` is itself a `std::initializer_list`. And only then , constructors are considered at which point overload resolution has a chance to match a constructor of `C` which accepts `std::initializer_list`. As of C++14 anyway -- the order of things in the list-initialization spec seems to jump around with every new standard draft

Comment: @M.M Good point about the empty list, I'll update my answer to reflect that. I don't think aggregate initialization conflicts with what I wrote, because a class can't both be an aggregate and have a `std::initializer_list` constructor.

Comment: Good answer. It also prevents this case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: @Ben: It seems that using `{}` is encouraged by the experts. I've [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46403621/why-uniform-initialization-initialization-with-braces-is-recommended) why, but unfortunately, no strong answer have been given yet.

Comment: @Ben honestly I don't think it matters too much, but some people like the safety of `{}` because it avoids accidental narrowing conversions

Answer (score 1):

The effect is same for this case.

`C c(3);` is [direct intialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization),

> the constructors of `T` are examined and the best match is selected by overload resolution. The constructor is then called to initialize the object.

`C c{3};` is [direct-list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11),

> If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of `T` participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the restriction that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed.

So for both cases `C::C(int)` is used for initializing the object.

---

Depending on the behavior of `C`, the other potential differences between `C c(3);` and `C c{3};` include:

- If `C` is an [aggregate type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) is preferred in list initialization.
- Ohterwise, if `C` has a constructor taking [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) then it's preferred in list initialization.
- Otherwise when the constructors are considered in [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Implicit_conversion_sequence_in_list-initialization), non-narrowing conversions are allowed in list initialization.

Comment: Thanks. May i ask which style of  `C c(3)` and `C c{3}` is more popular in other languages with OO? Is it correct that Java and C# don't have either?

Comment: @Ben I'm not sure, I guess it's `C c(3)`. List initialization is introduced from C++11, in C++ it's considered as *modern style*. :)