# Why would you declare a std::string using it's constructor?

Tags: c++, string, constructor, initialization, code-readability

Most people when declaring strings in C++, or most other languages, do it like so:

```
std::string example = "example";
```

However I've seen some code samples where it is done like this:

```
std::string example("example");
```

To me it seems like it needlessly obfuscates the code, particularly if there is a `using std::string` statement hiding somewhere above the declaration in the code making it look like

```
string example("example");
```

To some who may be new to the codebase or are coming from other languages it almost looks like it could be a method or  a function.

Is there any practical or performance based reason for using the constructor instead of the assignment operator or does it come down to just personal preference?

Comment: There is no "practical or performance based reason". And, just to welcome you to C++, these days we will also write `string example{"example"};`.

Comment: One reason can be that it **isn't** the assignment operator that is used, It just looks like that (an inheritance from C). Therefore some people prefer to use `=` only for *real* assigment, and not for initialization.

Comment: `auto example{"example"s};`

Comment: The reason is uniformity. Explicit constructors require direct initialization syntax. Not to mention it's the only way to initialize members in a constructor. Can't blame folks who opt to be uniform.

Comment: Because it reflects what happens.  In both cases, your examples are actually calling a constructor which accepts a `const char *` to initialise `example` with the literal `"example"`.    In other words, your two examples - despite the syntactic differences - do EXACTLY the same thing.    The main difference is the way they are interpreted at times - I've lost count of the number of times I've seen people insist the first is an assignment that calls `std::string`s `operator=()` function - which it doesn't.  People who get tired of fielding such claims therefore sometimes prefer the second form.

Comment: @Peter IMHO that should be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Obligatory [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) by Nicolai Josuttis.  An hour long presentation on the initialization syntax pain point in C++.

Comment: Looks like someplace, somewhere, Bjarne Stoustrup is drinking Uncle Bob's tears.

Comment: *"To some who may be new to the codebase or are coming from other languages it almost looks like it could be a method or a function."* -- Most constructors will look like a method by the logic. You just have to be used to the syntax.

Comment: @JesperJuhl   Yeah, okay.  I'll tidy up and expand a little, then post as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The practical reason for the second form is that it reflects what actually happens.   Your two examples actually - despite their syntactic differences - do exactly the same thing.

They are both calling a constructor which accepts a `const char *` to initialise `example` with the literal `"example"`.

The main difference is the way they are interpreted at times.  I've lost count of the number of times I've seen people insist that

```
std::string example = "example";
```

does an assignment that calls `std::string`s `operator=()` function - except that it doesn't.

People who get tired of fielding such claims (and prefer that someone looking at the code can understand what it actually does, wherever possible) therefore sometimes prefer the second form;

```
std::string example("example");
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you don't have a choice. Many [constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/121162/995714) are [explicit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) (even [some of `std::string`'s constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)) and you can't call it with the `type object = value` syntax, and for consistency `type object(value)` would be much better. Being explicit prevents mistakes on things like `std::vector<char> v = 'c';` or `MyString s = 'v';` that doesn't work as one expects

But [C++11 introduced the new `{}` initializer syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) and most modern coding conventions strongly prefer it, so you should use this instead

```
std::string example{ "example" }; // good
auto example{ "example"s };       // better
```

Even [ISO CPP's Core C++ Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) suggests that in [ES.23: Prefer the `{}` initializer syntax](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-list)

This has the advantage of preventing narrowing, and it works even for in-class initialization

```
struct foo {
    // OK
    std::string example1 = { "example" };
    std::string example2{ "example" };
    std::string example3 = "example";

    // Doesn't work
    std::string example4("example");
};
```

> To some who may be new to the codebase or are coming from other languages it almost looks like it could be a method or a function.

That's the well-known [most vexing parse issue in C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Both `std::string example(std::string(someIdentifier))` and `string example(string(someIdentifier))` can represent either a function declaration or a variable definition with initialization. If you learn C++ you have to learn the syntax

In fact [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14077608/995714) is one of the reasons of the introduction to the new `{}` initialization form

See also

- [What are the advantages of list initialization (using curly braces)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18222926/995714)
- [Why uniform initialization (initialization with braces) is recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46403621/995714)
- [When to use the brace-enclosed initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9976927/995714)