# Usage of Uniform Initialization Syntax

Tags: c++, c++11, uniform-initialization, member-initialization

If I have a class

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    Foo(int bar);

private:
    int m_bar;
}
```

What is the difference between these two ways to initialize it's member

```
Foo::Foo(int bar):
    m_bar(bar)
{

}

Foo::Foo(int bar):
    m_bar{ bar }
{

}
```

I was told on a code review to use Uniform Initialization Syntax, i.e. brace initialization.  Is there a difference in this case?  Or is it just a style preference?

Comment: The outcome is exactly the same in this case. The difference is purely stylistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of simple types, like *int* in your case, there is no difference. However, initialization of std::vector from STL will be completely different

```
std::vector<int> v1(3,1); // v1 consists of: 1, 1, 1
std::vector<int> v2{3,1}; // v2 consists of: 3, 1
```

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives) if you want to see why **generally** brace {} initialization is better, however quoting from Scott Meyer's book *Effective Modern C++*, which I highly recommend:

> [...] So why isn’t this Item
>   entitled something like “Prefer braced initialization syntax”?
>   The drawback to braced initialization is the sometimes-surprising behavior that
>   accompanies it. [...]