# Difference syntax to pass values to a constructor c++

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor

here i am using two syntax to pass values to a constructor :-

```
class A   
{

public:
    int x,y;

    A(int a,int b) : x(a),y(b){}
    void show()
    {
        cout<<x<<" "<<y<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{

    A obj1={5,6};//first method
    A obj2(9,10);//second method

    obj1.show();
    obj2.show();
}
```

And both are working fine
but when i remove the constructor function itself then also the first method is working fine .
please explain this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you remove this constructor, `class A` **becomes eligible for *aggregate initialization***, which is caused here by this *curly braces* syntax: `A obj1={5,6};` (that also has this equivalent form: `A obj1{5,6};` since C++11)

As you can [read here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), this applies in your case as `class A` then has none of the following:

1. private or protected non-static data members (applies until C++11)
2. user-declared constructors (applies since C++11 until C++17)
3. user-provided constructors (explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed) (applies since C++17 until C++20)
4. user-provided, inherited, or explicit constructors (explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed) (applies since C++20)
5. user-declared or inherited constructors
6. virtual, private, or protected (applies since C++17) base classes
7. virtual member functions
8. default member initializers (applies since C++11 until C++14)

---

In contrast, this syntax: `A obj2(9,10);` is performing [*direct-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), and it fails to compile once you remove the constructor due to [[dcl.init¶17.6.2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.2):

> [...] if the initialization is *direct-initialization* [...]
>   constructors are considered. [...] If no constructor applies [...] the initialization is
>   **ill-formed.**

---

Prior to removing the constructor, the same syntax `A obj1={5,6};` was calling it, while performing [*copy-list-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#copy-list-initialization).

---

What is *aggregate initialization*? It is the initialization of an instance of an [*aggregate type*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr) (either an array or a struct/class adhering to the above list) by the *braced-init-list* syntax. The arguments inside the braces must match the struct/class non-static data members *in declaration order*. It got significant boost in later versions of C++, as more syntactic forms for it were added to the language. Your usage of `={...}` is the only one in existence from before C++11.

---

The general pros and cons of using parentheses forms of initialization vs. brace initialization is discussed by many. A good place to get a comprehensive readout is at Item 7 of Scott Meyers' *Effective Modern C++*. That said, the foremost advantage of all [brace initialization forms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) is that [they don't allow *narrowing*.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18222927/2754173)

Answer (score 1):

```
A obj1={5,6};
```

This is using list initialization for the object, which is perfectly valid even without your 2 argument constructor being defined.

This may help you understand: [Why is list initialization (using curly braces) better than the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives)

Comment: Good call @3Dave, was just updating to clarify when I saw your comment :)

Comment: Also, nice link - I had no idea the brace initialization was that helpful.

Comment: does list initialization use some sort of internal constructor calling. what is the mechanism? is it simply used to make the structures of c++ behave like c structures