# c++ what is the difference between initializing an object with round or curly braces

Tags: c++, initialization

In c++ what is the difference between initializing an object with round or angled braces like in this example?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string x = "abc";

    std::string c(x);
    //std::string c{x};

    std::cout << "String c " << c;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Relevant: [Why is list initialization (using curly braces) better than the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18222926/580083)

Comment: Depend if there is constructor with `std::initializer_list` (as `std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}` vs `std::vector<int>(4, 0)`) and allowed/disallowed narrowing especially.