# Using {} as a default argument parameter type

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to know how this template works. Why did we use `T{}` to initialize the template parameter?

```
template<typename T, T Val = T{}>
T bar();
```

Comment: there is nothing that could "work", its just a declaration. What exactly dont you understand? Your second question nobody but you can answer, who is "we" anyhow?

Comment: Read up on [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

Answer (score 3):

The curly braces are [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), introduced in C++11.

It [value-initializes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) the template parameter `Val`, which is of templated type `T`.

You could have just as well done:

```
template<typename T, T Val = T()>
T bar();
```

For the advantages and disadvantages, see: [Why is list initialization (using curly braces) better than the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives)

Comment: To add to the answer: The curly braces existed prior to C++11 too. Back then it was called aggregate initialization (which is now a form of list initialization), and was for aggregate types only.