# difference between { } and equal sign variables

Tags: c++, for-loop, variables, initialization, list-initialization

I'm somewhat new to c++ programming. I couldn't find my answer any where on google so hopefully it can be answered here.

is there a difference between the following

```
unsigned int counter{ 1 };
```

or

```
unsigned int counter = 1;
```

the book uses the first option and its confusing to me because it doesn't explain the difference. below is the following code from the book i'm following.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib> // contains function prototype for rand()
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (unsigned int counter{ 1 }; counter <= 20; ++counter) {
        cout << setw(10) << (1 + rand() % 6);

        // if counter is divisible by 5, start a new line of output
        if (counter % 5 == 0) {
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is list initialization (using curly braces) better than the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they are two different types of initialization in C++.

- The first one, i.e., `unsigned int counter{ 1 };` is a [**direct initialization**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).
- Whereas, the second one, i.e., `unsigned int counter = 1;`, is a [**copy initialization**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

For all the details you can directly refer to the documentation.

However, I can emphasize:

> Copy-initialization is less permissive than direct-initialization: explicit constructors are not converting constructors and are not considered for copy-initialization.

[Initialization references here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)

For `unsigned int` type (such in your case), there are no real differences between the two initializations.

---

**Note**
The usage of curly braces in the first statement (`unsigned int counter{ 1 }`) provides an additional constraint:

> Otherwise (**if T is not a class type**), if the braced-init-list has only one element [...], T is **direct-initialized** [...], except that **narrowing conversions are not allowed**.

In other words, the usage of curly braces in the initialization does not allow data looseness.

That is:

```
unsigned int counter{ 12.3 };  // error!!!
```

won't compile because you are trying to initialize an integer with a floating-point value.

Note this is a "property" of curly braces in the initialization. *It is not strictly related to the initialization type*.

In fact, you can also write:

```
unsigned int counter = { 12.3 };  // error!
```

which is, instead, a *copy initialization*, but having curly braces does not allows narrowing conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int x;
    explicit A( int x = 0 ) : x( x ) {}
};

int main()
{
    A a1 { 10 };
    std::cout << "a1.x = " << a1.x << '\n';

//    A a2 = { 10 };
}
```

In this declaration

```
A a1 { 10 };
```

there is used the direct initialization.

And in the commented declaration

```
//    A a2 = { 10 };
```

that can be also rewritten like

```
//    A a2 = 10;
```

there is used the copy-initialization. But the constructor declared with the specifier `explicit`. So the compiler will issue an error. That is it is unable to convert the integer object `10` to the type of `A` implicitly.

You could write instead

```
    A a2 = A{ 10 };
```

That is calling the constructor explicitly.

Of course for fundamental types there is no difference because neither constructor is applied except that narrowing conversion is not allowed when the braced initialization is used as for example

```
int x { 1.0 };
```

There is a big difference when the type specifier is the placeholder `auto`.

For example

```
auto x = 10;
```

`x` has the type `int`.

```
auto x { 10 };
```

`x` again has the type `int`.

```
auto x = { 10 };
```

Now `x` has the type `std::initializer_list<int>`.

For example you could rewrite your loop

```
for (unsigned int counter{ 1 }; counter <= 20; ++counter) {
```

the following way

```
for ( auto counter{ 1u }; counter <= 20; ++counter) {
```

but you may not write

```
for ( auto counter = { 1u }; counter <= 20; ++counter) {
```

because in this case the type of the variable `counter` is `std::initializer_list<unsigned int>`.

So in general you have the following forms of initializations

```
T x = value;
T x = { value };
T x( value );
T x { value };
```

For example

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x1 = 1;

    std::cout << "x1 = " << x1 << '\n';

    int x2 = ( 2 );

    std::cout << "x2 = " << x2 << '\n';

    int x3( 3 );

    std::cout << "x3 = " << x3 << '\n';

    int x4{ 4 };

    std::cout << "x4 = " << x4 << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
x1 = 1
x2 = 2
x3 = 3
x4 = 4
```

But there is one more situation when instead of `T()` you should use `T{}` as an initializer. It is when template functions are used.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

template <class>
void f()
{
    std::cout << "f<T>() is called\n";
}

template <int>
void f()
{
    std::cout << "f<int>() is called\n";
}

int main()
{
    f<int()>();
    f<int{}>();
}
```

Its output is

```
f<T>() is called
f<int>() is called
```

The construction `int()` used as a template argument specifiers the type template argument `int` while the construction `int{}` used as a template argument specifiers a non-type template argument of the type `int` equal to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned int counter = 1 ;`
This style of initialization is inherited from C language.

`unsigned int counter {1} ;`
This style of initialization is of C++.

The difference is if you provide a wrong value while using C++ style initialization 
for example:

`unsigned int counter {-1} ;`
This will give error (use `-std=c++11` to compile it)

But this will not give any error.

`unsigned int counter = -1 ;`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other explanations above.
I would use the first option(unsigned int counter{ 1 };) to initialize a list of values for a variable and for a single value, I would prefer to use the second option(unsigned int counter = 1;)

Hope this helps.