# cppcheck warns about the pointer to local variable in list initialization

Tags: c++, cppcheck

I analyzed some code with cppcheck for errors and code quality. I came across an error which I think is an false positive. The following code example shows the problem (marked with comment).

cppcheck - v 1.89

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::string func() {
    std::vector<char> data{};
    data.push_back('a');
    data.push_back('b');
    data.push_back('c');
    return std::string{ data.data(), data.size() }; // error marked here
    // severity: error
    // line: 12
    // summary: Returning object that points to local variable 'data' that will be invalid when returning.
}

int main() {
    std::string ret{};
    {
        ret = func();
    }
    std::cout << ret << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If i use `()` instead of `{}`, it resolves the error.

**EDIT**

When I debug the example with `()` or `{}`, there is totally no difference. I use Visual Studio 17 with C++14.

Comment: Your line std::string will invoke the constructor for the string class, it requires () because its a function call.  {} is used for data initialization and scoping.

Comment: @SPlatten when I debug the example, there is totally no difference in the behavior.

Comment: Cppcheck has been broken for years. @SPlatten It is direct list initialization syntax invoking constructor.

Comment: @VTT would you discourage me to use it in an productive context?

Comment: Well, using it won't do any harm, but it is not that helpful and struggles to parse modern syntax. I'd recommend PVS studio.

Comment: If what's between the `{}` can be interpreted as a `std::initializer_list<char>`, you  have a problem (which can be fixed by using `()`). Otherwise, using `{}` is fine. When in doubt (for classes that have a `std::initializer_list` constructor), it's typically safer to stick with `()`. Ref. eg. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives/37228443#37228443).

Comment: Ie. : I suspect cppcheck just "plays it safe".

Comment: As the answers indicate, it really was a false positive. There is a corresponding [ticket in the bug tracker](https://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/9473) and it has already been fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/commit/4ebf54d0902eb930cf54bf7b10214b353450e665). So Cppcheck 1.90 will no longer have this false positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the rule was for before C++11:

`{/*..*/}` was only use for aggregate initialization before C++11, so `T{ data.data(), data.size() }` could only store the future dangling pointer thus the diagnostic.

With `T(data.data(), data.size() )`, it is a regular constructor call, so it actually depends of `T` constructor, so no diagnostic can be safely be done without inspecting `T` constructor (and I doubt than cppcheck does inspect) (and BTW it is safe for `std::string`).

So indeed, it is a false positive.

Answer (score 2):

It's a false-positive as the string ctor makes a copy of the passed char* string.