# C++ Assignment to variable of summation between curly brackets

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm currently implementing a class for an assignment for my C++ course, 
but there is one thing I don't fully grasp. As an example I'll use integers, to make this question more general.
Let's say we have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main{     
    int p = { 1 + 2 + 3 };
    int q = 1 + 2 + 3;
    std::cout << p << " - " << q << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the value for both `p` and `q` equal? What is the purpose of the curly brackets? Is there any difference in the way the program is executed or in terms of performance? I'm having a hard time finding the answer to these questions online so thought I'd ask it here.

Comment: Research aggregate initialization.

Comment: There will be no performance change. Google `c++14 curley bracket initialize` for a better understanding of the difference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a scalar type, all of these syntaxes:

```
T p = e;
T p(e);
T p{e};
T p = {e};
```

mean that `p` is initialized with the value of `e`. (These different syntaxes can have different meanings when `T` is a class type.)

However, with the brace syntax, there is an additional constraint that the conversion must not be [narrowing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Narrowing_conversions):

```
int p = 2.5;  // ok
int q = {2.5};  // error
```

This check is done at compile time, so it should have no effect on performance at run time.