# Why is this call to the overloaded function ambiguous?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, overloading, initializer-list

Consider this program-

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
void fun(const std::string& val) {
}

void fun(std::vector<std::string> val) {
}

int main()
{
    std::set<std::string> example;
    fun({std::begin(example), std::end(example)});
}
```

On compilation, I am hitting into these errors-

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:13:49: error: call of overloaded 'fun(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous
   13 |     fun({std::begin(example), std::end(example)});
      |                                                 ^
prog.cc:4:6: note: candidate: 'void fun(const string&)'
    4 | void fun(const std::string& val) {
      |      ^~~
prog.cc:7:6: note: candidate: 'void fun(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >)'
    7 | void fun(std::vector<std::string> val) {
      |      ^~~
```

I understand that `std::string` has a constructor overload that takes in an `initializer_list` like so-

```
basic_string( std::initializer_list<char> ilist,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

and `std::vector<std::string>` has an overload that looks like so-

```
vector( std::initializer_list<std::string> init,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

So, it is clear that these 2 methods differ in their types. One takes in an `initializer_list` of `char` and the other of type `std::string`.

In my code when I am passing an initializer list of strings cos I pass 2 iterators to a set of strings.

Even then, why does the compiler flag this as an ambiguous call?

Comment: "_In my code when I am passing an initializer list of strings cos I pass 2 iterators to a set of strings."_ No, your initializer list has two iterators; it is not a list of strings.

Comment: Are you aware that you don't _have_ an initializer list of `std::string`, but instead of `std::set<std::string>::const_iterator`?

Comment: Furthermore it's not actually an `std::initializer_list` unless & until that's actually what the initializer expression binds to. e.g. any `void fun(T)` will work if `T` had a `T(std::set<std::string>::const_iterator, std::set<std::string>::const_iterator`). Or something that worked equivalently given some conversion chain....

Comment: @MooingDuck Where's the `const_` from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler sees an ambiguous call to the following two constructors (note that neither of them take an initializer list):

```
template <class InputIt>
std::vector::vector (InputIt first, InputIt last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

and

```
template <class InputIt>
std::string::string (InputIt first, InputIt last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Now, if you were to actually call the `std::string` constructor with those iterator arguments you'd get an error, because they don't dereference to a char. But since that check is not part of the function declaration (e.g. via SFINAE), you're getting the ambiguity error instead.

Comment: Interesting. But the compilation error( the part which says `call of overloaded 'fun(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'`) seems to indicate that the compiler has deduced it as an `initializer list`. I'm guessing this initializer list is not the same as `std::initializer_list>`?

Comment: Are you using Microsoft's compiler? I've seen that as a goto message when the compiler is confused.

Comment: Also, the compiler error indicates that `{begin(), end()}` is being considered as one parameter. Why is it trying to match with constructors that take at least 2 parameters?

Comment: @lakeweb No, GCC 10 and C++14

Comment: @PavanManjunath That's because it is a literal "initializer list" to initialize something (which may or may not be a `std::initializer_list`, for example, here it is either a vector or string), which hasn't been resolved to a type yet, so that's all the compiler can say. Like `std::vector<std::string>{5, "abc"}` doesn't call the `std::initializer_list` constructor, but it is still initialized with an brace-enclosed-init-list (With 2 arguments).

Comment: As an aside I guess this sort of scenario is why more recent library additions have phrases like "this function does not participate in overload resolution unless..." scattered throughout them, an allusion to `std::enable_if` which may make spurious errors less common but also makes reference material much harder to parse!

Comment: @PavanManjunath "brace-enclosed initializer list" and `std::initializer_list` are not the same thing.

Comment: @PavanManjunath _"Also, the compiler error indicates that {begin(), end()} is being considered as one parameter."_ No, it isn't. You're misintepreting it.

Comment: @ Artyer, thanks for your comment. I will pay more attention the next time I see that error.

Comment: @Artyer Thanks for the nice example. One last qn- in my case the brace-enclosed-list has 2 elements, both of them being std::set iterators. In such case, shouldn't it have binded to the vector constructor that takes in a std::initializer_list? since `std::initializer_list<>` ctors are preferred over other ctors?(https://stackoverflow.com/a/18224556/457237)

Comment: @PavanManjunath The constructor you're talking about has the following signature: `vector (std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());`. In this case the types in what would/could be an `std::initializer_list` are clearly not `T`, but `std::set<T>::const_iterator`.