# How does this list-like initialization work?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, list-initialization, copy-elision

I know about several types of initialization in C++ and recently learned why [list initialization should be preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives). But what about this code? [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/750921c35a229eff)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
    A(int x, std::string y) { std::cout << "normal\n"; }

    A(const A& obj) { std::cout << "copy\n"; }
};

int main(){
    A a({1, "2"}); // strange initialization
}
```

Prints:

```
normal
```

It looks like some kind of list initialization mixed with a construtor call using parentheses. So I thought it would create a temporary instance of `A` from `{1, "2"}` and then call the copy-constructor. But that doesn't happen. Instead it behaves like list-initialization. Maybe I'm just confused by the syntax and it *is* list-initialization?

If it is, how does the syntax work here? If not, what kind of initialization is this?

Comment: _It looks like some kind of list initialization mixed with a construtor call using parentheses. So I thought it would create a temporary instance of A from {1, "2"} and then call the copy-constructor._ I agree but you forgot about [copy-elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I thought it would create a temporary instance of `A` from `{1, "2"}` and then call the copy-constructor.

You're right. Here the object `a` is initialized via the constructor `A::A(int x, std::string y)` directly because of [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

You can compile with `-fno-elide-constructors` option (with pre-C++17 mode, since C++17 this kind of copy elision is guaranteed), you'll get

```
normal
copy
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/G43Q3O1WA6XNJ8WA)

Answer (score 1):

`A a({1, "2"});` is actually [`copy-list-initialization`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) where *braced-init-list* is used in place of a constructor argument.