# Initializing class members with {}

Tags: c++, initialization

Someone gave me (part of) the following code:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int x = {};
    int y = {};

};
```

I never saw this syntax before, what does initialization with `{}` mean?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives

Comment: It's inline [*value initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) of the members. In short, `int x = {};` is the same as `int x = 0;`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but I can't just replace it with `int x = 0` unless it is `const`?

Comment: @BennyK `int x = 0;` should be fine. https://wandbox.org/permlink/NEGqlNIcI8nieHe5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is list initialization (using curly braces) better than the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the C++11 standard there are two ways to initialize member variables:

1. Using the constructor initialization list as "usual":

   ```
   struct Foo
   {
       int x;

       Foo()
           : x(0)
       {
       }
   };
   ```
2. Use the new *inline* initialization where members are getting their "default" values using normal initialization syntax:

   ```
   struct Foo
   {
       int x = 0;
   };
   ```

Both these ways are for many values and types equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

This is [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (since C++11),

> Through a default member initializer, which is a brace or equals initializer included in the member declaration and is used if the member is omitted from the member initializer list of a constructor.

The initialization itself is [copy-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11), as the effect, the data member `x` and `y` would be value-initialized (and zero-initialized as built-in type) to `0`.

Comment: It's default member initializer, not default initializer list.

Comment: @songyuanyao The data member would be initialized to its default value. In the case of `int` it is `0`. But for classes it will mean constructing with the default constructor.

Comment: @EnoshCohen There's no "default value" for int in this context.

Comment: There is an "initial value" for scalar types, maybe the term is not accurate: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization