# Differences among `unique_ptr<Sample> sp1(new Sample);` `unique_ptr<Sample> sp1(new Sample());` and , `unique_ptr<Sample> sp2(new Sample{});`

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, unique-ptr

What are the differences  among `unique_ptr<Sample> sp1(new Sample);` `unique_ptr<Sample> sp1(new Sample());`  and , `unique_ptr<Sample> sp2(new Sample{});`? I found that they are all legal indeed.You could check it on http://cpp.sh/3icui.

I am a novice in C++.I thought over and over but still could get the idea.I would be thankful for any hint on this question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Sample {
public:
    Sample() { cout << "Sample Constuctor" << endl; }
    ~Sample() { cout << "Sample Destructor" << endl; }
    void publicFn() { cout << "This is public function of class" << endl; }
};
int main() {
    unique_ptr<Sample> sp1(new Sample{});
    unique_ptr<Sample> sp2(new Sample());
    unique_ptr<Sample> sp3(new Sample);
    sp1->publicFn();
    sp2->publicFn();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your question you said `new Sample[]`, but in your code it seems to be `new Sample()`, which one is correct?

Comment: @songyuanyao  The latter one is right.Sorry to disturbing you.I have modified it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is list initialization (using curly braces) better than the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives)

Comment: I would see it right now.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have the same efffect here.

`new Sample()` performs [value initalization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), the object is initialized by the default constructor of `Sample`.

`new Sample{}` performs [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11), as the effect the object is also [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) by the default constructor of `Sample`.

BTW: `new Sample` has the same effect too, it performs [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) and the object is also initialized by the default constructor.

The effect of these initalization styles depend on contexts, especially on how the type behaves. For class `Sample` they all have the same effect.

Comment: Thank you.What about `unique_ptr<Sample> sp3(new Sample);`?

Comment: @sunshilong369 Answer revised.

Answer (score 1):

{} can be used to directly initialize member data in the absence of a constructor.

() can be used only without any parameters in the absence of a constructor that takes parameters.

In your case, they will perform the same because you have a defined constructor.

A quick example:

```
struct h
{
    int tmp=3;
    int k=3;
};


int main()
{
    h h1{6, 4};
    h h2;

    std::cout << h1.tmp << std::endl;
    std::cout << h2.tmp << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No problem. Please let me know if I can help further.

Comment: It's so kind of you.I will.

Comment: Your example [doesn't compile](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/CnRtqs). Furthermore, `()` [can be used](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/c2XP8d) in your example.

Comment: It compiled on my machine with g++. It seems that g++ does things differently. @sunshilong369, according to the online compiler we need to have a constructor that takes 2 parameters in order to use {}.

Comment: @bhristov  Which version gcc do you use?

Comment: @sunshilong369 I am using g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0