# complex<> using list initializer vs constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

I'm reading Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed. Page 162 Types and Declarations.  Specifically, where the following is allowed to construct a `complex<>` object.

The book comments that case **A** is "use constructor".  Is case **A** really a list initializer and the constructor method of initialization is performed in **B** or **C**?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    complex<double> z = { 0, 3.14 }; // A
    complex<double> h(0, 3.14); // B
    complex<double> i{0, 3.14}; // C

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All three cases are initialised using the same constructor.  B does direct initialisation.   Since C++11, cases A and C do aggregate initialisation (or, more specifically, copy list initialisation and direct list initialisation, respectively).

Comment: Is one better than the other?  All these ways of initializing an object is becoming confusing :(

Comment: They are alternative ways of performing initialisation.

Comment: @notaorb There're subtle differences among them, even not in this case. See [Why is list initialization (using curly braces) better than the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18222926/3309790)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `complex<double> z = { 0, 3.14 }; // A` performs [copy-list-initliazation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11).
- `complex<double> h(0, 3.14); // B` performs [direct initliazation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).
- `complex<double> i{0, 3.14}; // C` performs [direct-list-initliazation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11).

The effects are all the same for this case; objects are initialized by the [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/complex) `complex::complex(double, double)`.