# No suitable constructor exists to convert from "float" to "_D3DCOLORVALUE"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, directx, directx-11, directx-12

I am currently trying to learn DirectX 11 using C++ in Visual Studio 2017 and have run into a problem.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3d12.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>

// include D3D Librararies
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d12.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "D3DCompiler.lib")

// Definitions
#define SCREEN_WIDTH    800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT   600

// Global Declarations
IDXGISwapChain *swapchain;              // Pointer to Swap Chain Buffer
ID3D11DeviceContext *devcon;            // Pointer to managing Device for GPU
ID3D11Device *dev;                      // Pointer to GPU
ID3D11RenderTargetView *backBuffer;     // A pointer to an object that holds info about the render target
ID3D11VertexShader *pVS;                // The Vertex shader
ID3D11PixelShader *pPS;                 // The Pixel Shader


struct VERTEX {
   FLOAT X, Y, Z;           // Position
   D3DCOLORVALUE Color; // Color
};

// float color2[4] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
VERTEX OurVertex = { 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,  D3DCOLORVALUE(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)}; // No suitable constructor exists to convert from "float" to "_D3DCOLORVALUE"
```

There is an error inside of OurVertex, where C++ can't seem to convert the float numbers in D3DCOLORVALUE() into a D3DCOLORVALUE item. I tried looking at other solutions, and couldn't find any to solve my case.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: What about `VERTEX OurVertex = {0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, D3DCOLORVALUE{1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}};` ?

Comment: Thank You, that worked.

So, Curly Braces are used for D3DCOLORVALUE. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Check the documentation, `_D3DCOLORVALUE` is a `struct`, so you probably need to do it like `D3DCOLORVALUE{1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}`

Answer (score 0):

`D3DCOLORVALUE` doesn't have a constructor taking 4 `float`s. You should use [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

```
VERTEX OurVertex = {0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, D3DCOLORVALUE{1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}};
```

Or simpler:

```
VERTEX OurVertex = {0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,  {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}};
```

Answer (score 0):

@TedLyngmo
Ted basically said it all about how you should do this.

However based on your comment earlier,

> Curly Braces are used for D3DCOLORVALUE. I will keep that in mind

You seem to be thinking this as a special case. Instead, the way of understanding that should be whether you are calling a function or you are creating an object.

With modern C++s, list initialization are preferred in most cases. Check this question: [Why is list initialization (using  curly braces) better than the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives)

Basically, often time you could use `myClass objectName { myValues };` to declare an object, or `myClass { myValues };` if you are to create a temporary one. So that parentheses could be reserved for either function calls or objects with `std::initializer_list` ctors.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `D3DCOLORVALUE` is specifically a Direct3D 9 construct. Many people will use four floats for per-vertex color (at least when starting out), but if you wanted to use a packed color format the [DirectXMath](https://walbourn.github.io/introducing-directxmath/) type [XMCOLOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/directxpackedvector/ns-directxpackedvector-xmcolor) in the `DirectX::PackedVector` namespace matches the old `D3DCOLORVALUE`.

For Direct3D 11 functions that take an array of four floats for the color (such as `ClearRenderTargetView`, DirectXMath also defines a number of color constants in the `DirectXColors.h` header.

> As you are new to DirectX 11, you should take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).