# Why does using curley braces when creating an object, calls 2 constructor if one constructor have initializer list

Tags: c++, list-initialization

I happen to come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18224556/11448069), and I don't get it, why `Foo c{a}` called the 2 constructors. I know that every time an object is created, the constructor, is called, so why does it called the `foo(std::initializer_list<Foo>)` even if he did not do this `Foo c{{a}}` or `Foo c({a})`?

> ```cpp
> struct Foo {
>     Foo() {}
>
>     Foo(std::initializer_list<Foo>) {
>         std::cout << "initializer list" << std::endl;
>     }
>
>    Foo(const Foo&) {
>        std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl;
>    }
> };
>
> int main() {
>     Foo a;
>     Foo b(a); // copy ctor
>     Foo c{a}; // copy ctor (init. list element) + initializer list!!!
> }
> ```

Comment: Because the list initialization constructor has precedence in that case, as defined by the standard

Comment: Let me cite [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list): _The underlying array is a temporary array of type `const T[N]`, in which each element is copy-initialized (except that narrowing conversions are invalid) from the corresponding element of the original initializer list._

Comment: from the answer "you should be aware that the initializer_list<> constructor is preferred to the other constructors" does this not answer your question? (serious question, really not sure if that is sufficient to clarify your doubts)

Comment: I mean, why can he call 2 constructors? should be it only one?

Comment: initializer list constructors are different. There are special rules for them. You won't understand how it works by just considering `std::initializer_list` as a type like others

Comment: GCC and Clang [disagree](https://godbolt.org/z/7h154a) with each other.

Comment: @Evg bug in clang, or am I missing something that makes both valid outcomes?

Comment: @Evg, I got more confused, why is that? if the `std::initializer_list` is more preferred, then why did Clang outputted, the non-initializer_list constructor? is it differ from compiler to compiler?

Comment: @RenzAguirre, the second constructor is understandable: internally, `initializer_list` holds const objects, to construct those objects (here, just one object) a copy constructor invocation is needed. Why GCC and Clang differ and which compiler is right (or both) I'm not ready to say now.

Comment: Different compilers have different bugs. This one is a clang bug.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization

Here we see:

> T object { arg }; (2) (since C++11)

> 2. initialization of an object of non-class type with a single brace-enclosed initializer (**note: for class types and other uses of braced-init-list, see list-initialization**)

In https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization there is following bullet:

> If T is an aggregate class and the initializer list has a single element of the same or derived type (possibly cv-qualified), the object is initialized **from that element** (by copy-initialization for copy-list-initialization, or by direct-initialization for direct-list-initialization). (since C++14)

And returning to direct initialization:

> the constructors of T are examined and the best match is selected by overload resolution. The constructor is then called to initialize the object.

So, it seems that in this situation clang is right to call copy constructor and GCC is wrong. At least since C++14.

Comment: Foo is not an aggregate.

Comment: It is actually a long-standing [clang bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23812).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Sorry but I'm really having a hard time understanding it. If that's the case, I still don't understand how and why did `Foo c{a}` called two constructor, should it be only one, making clang output right? because its more intuitive in my mind. more specifically, if the precedence of the `std::initializer_list<Foo>` constructor is higher, should it only called that constructor? do you maybe have examples for me to better understand it?

Comment: @RenzAguirre How do you pass an argument to that constructor?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. either `Foo({n}}` or `Foo({n})` is this right?

Comment: @RenzAguirre Um, no. You pass an argument **by copy**. Passing an argument to any function by copy involves a copy constructor.