# C++ Constructor is ambiguous with std::map of the same key/value types

Tags: c++

Here's a class definition as an example.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <map>

template <class T>
class Collection
{
private:
  std::map<std::string, T> data;

public:
  Collection() {}

  Collection(std::map<std::string, T> d)
  {
    data = d;
  }
};
```

This works fine when initializing Collections with `int`s, `char`s, and even `vector` templated types. However, when initializing a one with a `string` and calling the second overloaded constructor, like:

```cpp
Collection<std::string> col({
  { "key", "value" }
});
```

It does not compile, and throws this exit error:

```cpp
main.cpp:24:22: error: call to constructor of 'Collection<std::__cxx11::string>'
      (aka 'Collection<basic_string<char> >') is ambiguous
  Collection<string> col({
                     ^   ~
main.cpp:8:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor)
class Collection
      ^
main.cpp:8:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor)
main.cpp:16:3: note: candidate constructor
  Collection(map<string, T> d)
  ^
```

The strange thing is, while this notation is fine with other types, and this breaks, this notation works for `string`:

```cpp
Collection<std::string> col(std::map<std::string, std::string>({
  { "key", "value" }
}));
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Brace-hell: `Collection<std::string> col{{ { "key", "value" } }};` [example](https://godbolt.org/z/5sqnP5)

Comment: It would be far more efficient to write your constructor using `std::move` and an initializer list instead: `Collection(std::map<std::string, T> d) : data(std::move(d)) { }`. Doing so would avoid a pointless default initialization and copy-assignment

Comment: Constructors normally take constant references to non-POD values. You're code will use a copy and move, whereas using a reference will only use a copy

Comment: Actually @CSM, constructors which copy their arguments normally take by value and use `std::move()` so as to copy only once (as shown by @alter igel).  I expect that's omitted from the question as it's irrelevant to the ambiguity issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a fun one.

A `map` can be constructed from two iterators:

```
template<class InputIterator>
  map(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
      const Compare& comp = Compare(), const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

Notably, this constructor is not required to check that `InputIterator` is an iterator at all, let alone that the result of dereferencing it is convertible to the `map`'s value type. Actually trying to construct the map will fail, of course, but to overload resolution, `map` is constructible from any two arguments of the same type.

So with

```
Collection<std::string> col({
  { "key", "value" }
});
```

The compiler sees two interpretations:

- outer braces initializes a `map` using the `map`'s initializer-list constructor, inner braces initializes a `pair` for that initializer-list constructor.
- outer braces initializes a `Collection`, inner braces initializes a `map` using the "iterator-pair" constructor.

Both are user-defined conversions in the ranking, there is no tiebreaker between the two, so the call is ambiguous - even though the second, if chosen, would result in an error somewhere inside `map`'s constructor.

When you use braces on the outermost layer as well:

```
Collection<std::string> col{{
  { "key", "value" }
}};
```

There is [a special rule in the standard](https://wg21.link/over.best.ics.general#4.5) that precludes the second interpretation.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful explanation. I'm still confused on why using curly brackets instead of parentheses works, though. Is this due to `{}` as an operator being overloaded and thus not a constructor?

Comment: @acikek the `{}` notation for initialization is called list initialization. For more details, see this amazing answer to a previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18222927/15284149

Comment: @MysteriousUser Thank you, this is all very interesting to learn about. Little intricacies like this are why I like c++.

Comment: @acikek This part (the brace-hell) is _not_ why I like C++ :-) It shouldn't be complicated to initialize but ... there are so many layers of things that need to be handled. Uniform initialization - any day now ....

Answer (score 7):

In this case, you are missing a {} that encloses the map `{{ "key", "value" }}`

EDIT: Sorry I can't comment on T.C's answer because of insufficient reputation. In any case, thanks for brilliantly highlighting the point of ambiguity.

I wanted to add on to their answer - to give a complete picture of why constructing with {} does not result in this ambiguity but constructing with () does.

The key difference between braced and parentheses initialization is that during constructor overload resolution, braced initializers are matched to std::initializer_list parameters if at all possible, even if other constructors offer better matches. This is why constructing with {} can resolve the ambiguity.

(This is taken from Item 7 of Scott Myers' Effective Modern C++)

Comment: This works, but why does the lack of this (and putting it in parentheses instead of curly brackets) only affect `std::string`?

Comment: @acikek not sure about the exact logic or explanation here, but the fact `{string, string}` is homogenous, make it thinks it might be a C-style array.

Comment: That's a good question and I am trying to figure it out. It definitely has to do with the subtle differences between constructing with braces vs parentheses. 

The question of why does it affect std::string - here's my intuition. When you have `{ {std::string, std::string} }` as the parameter, it could be construed as an an array of `array<std::string>`. 

I experimented with changing the default key to int and got the same results when both key and values are int.

Comment: To make it more unambiguous, you could try `Collection<std::string> col(std::map<std::string, std::string> {{"key", "value"}});` and see that it is able to construct `Collection` correctly.

Comment: I did put that in my question as unexpected behavior. I think you're onto something with the arrays.

Comment: There is no relevant `initializer_list` constructor here.