# Constructor - Copying Const Reference VS Moving Copied Value

Tags: c++, constructor

I couldn't find the answer so I'm asking it here. What's the difference between THIS:

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(std::string string)
        : m_String(std::move(string)) {}

private:
    std::string m_String;
}
```

And THAT:

```cpp
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(const std::string& string)
        : m_String(string) {}

private:
    std::string m_String;
}
```

I know that using a constructor from `Bar` copies data exactly from the value, but I don't really know what exactly happens when calling the `Foo` constructor.
Is there a difference in using constructor from `Foo` or `Bar`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use strings but a type where you can observe copying and moving:

```
#include <iostream>

struct test {
    test() { std::cout << "constructor\n"; }
    test(const test&) { std::cout << "copy\n";}
    test(test&&) { std::cout << "move\n"; }
};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(test t) : t(std::move(t)) {}    
private:
    test t;
};

class Bar {
public:
    Bar(const test& t) : t(t) {}   
private:
    test t;
};

int main() {
    test t1;
    Foo f{t1};
    std::cout << "...........\n";
    test t2;
    Bar b{t2};
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/Ps4x3sqK5):

```
constructor
copy
move
...........
constructor
copy
```

Calling `Foo`s constructor copies `t1` to the constructors parameter, because it is taken by value and then the member is move constructed from the parameter.

Calling `Bar`s constructor takes a reference (no copy, no move) and uses that to copy construct the member.

---

If the intention was to avoid the copying, you would provide a constructor that takes a `test&&`:

```
struct Baz {
    Baz(test&& t) : t(std::move(t)) {}
    test t;
};
```

Then `Baz z(test{});` will construct a `test` and the member will be move constructed from that temporary. No copies involved.

Comment: I know it's a bit different topic, but maybe could you shortly explain why `Foo f{t1};` was called with curly braces and the Bar with "typical" `()`? I read about it milion times but still can't get it

Comment: I totally forgot I can create a class which on certain constructor will tell me what happened. Thanks very much for explanation.

Comment: @RobertKwiatkowski [Explanation about curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives)

Comment: @RobertKwiatkowski the reason I used `()` for `Bar` was just carelessness. There is no huge difference in this example and here it is basically a matter of style. I am using `{}` here to be consistent with other cases where it does make a difference