# Variable is not a type

Tags: c++, class

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Course
{
    public:
        string name;
        string instructorInCharge;
        int numberOfStudents;
        int totalMarks;
        Course(string u, string v, int p, int q){
            this->name=u;
            this->instructorInCharge=v;
            this->numberOfStudents=p;
            this->totalMarks=q;

        }
    
    vector<int> studentMarks (numberOfStudents);

    

};
class Labs:public Course
{
   
        vector<int>labMarks(numberOfStudents);

};

int main()
{
    Course c("Rahul","Hota",200,300);
    cout<<"hello there";
}
```

When I compile this code I’m getting the following error:

```
1.cpp:20:31: error: 'numberOfStudents' is not a type
   20 |     vector<int> studentMarks (numberOfStudents);
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1.cpp:28:29: error: 'numberOfStudents' is not a type
   28 |         vector<int>labMarks(numberOfStudents);
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Please tell me what my mistake is.
numberostudents was supposed to be the size of the vector. But not any function.

Comment: What do you expect that line to mean?

Comment: `vector<int> studentMarks (numberOfStudents);` Is `numberOfStudents` supposed to be an argument? What type should the argument have?

Comment: Look up most vexing parse.   Compiler views `vector<int> studentMarks (numberOfStudents);` as a declaration of a function named `studentMarks()` that accepts an argument of type `numberOfStudents` and returns a `vector<int>`.   Remove the bit in `()` entirely, and initialise the vector in the constructor initialiser list.   Same in class `Labs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want in-class initialization, you may do this:

```
vector<int> studentMarks = vector<int>(numberOfStudents);
```

Now the default constructor will initialize `studentMarks` with `vector<int>(numberOfStudents)` when an instance of `Course` is created.

However, this will cause undefined behavior since `numberOfStudents` is not initialized before the initialization of `studentMarks`. You could use the member initalizer list instead:

```
Course(std::string u, std::string v, int p, int q)
    : name(std::move(u)),
      instructorInCharge(std::move(v)),
      numberOfStudents(p),
      totalMarks(q),
      studentMarks(numberOfStudents)
{
}
```

and likewise for the `Labs` class:

```
class Labs : public Course {
public:
    Labs(std::string u, std::string v, int p, int q)
        : Course(u, v, p, q),  // initialize the base class part of a `Labs`
          labMarks(p)          // initialize the added member variable
    {
    }
    std::vector<int> labMarks;
};
```

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Right, I forgot that. Anyway, thanks. You improved the answer.

Answer (score 8):

> ```
> vector<int> studentMarks (numberOfStudents);
> ```

This is a function declaration. The return type is `vector<int>`, the name is `studentMarks` and it accepts a single parameter of type `numberOfStudents`. Except, as the error points out, `numberOfStudents` is not a type.

You cannot use parentheses to specify a default member initialiser. You have to either use curly braces:

```
T member {value};
```

or "equals" initialiser:

```
T member = value;
```

Note however, that you don't initialise `numberOfStudents` member, but rather assign it later in the constructor body. This assignment is after `studentMarks` has been initialised, and thus the default member initialiser of `studentMarks` won't reflect the size that was assigned. Rather, the behaviour of the program would be undefined due to the use of an indeterminate value. This can be fixed by initialising `numberOfStudents` in the member initialiser list.

Comment: numberofstudents was supposed to be the size of the vector so that it could hold all the marks of the students of particular count numberofstudents, why is it interpreting it as a function

Comment: @SaiRahul It is interpreted as a function declaration because that is the syntax of a function declaration. If you write a function declaration, the compiler cannot know that you didn't intend to write a function declaration. If you intend to define a member with a default member initialiser, then follow the advice in my answer.

Comment: @SaiRahul, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18222926/4688321

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `resize` method of `std::vector`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Course
{
public:
    string name;
    string instructorInCharge;
    int numberOfStudents;
    int totalMarks;

    
    vector<int> studentMarks;
    
    Course(string u, string v, int p, int q){
        this->name = u;
        this->instructorInCharge = v;
        this->numberOfStudents = p;
        this->totalMarks = q;

        this->studentMarks.resize(numberOfStudents);
    }
};
class Labs : public Course
{
    vector<int> labMarks;
public:
    Labs(string u, string v, int p, int q) : Course(u, v, p, q)
    {
        labMarks.resize(p);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Course c("Rahul","Hota",200,300);
    cout<<"hello there";
}
```

Comment: I believe .resize() is what OP intends.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, yes you are right. Made the edits.