# Weird c++ copy constructor without default constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, default-constructor

Me and a colleague of mine had a debate about wether

```
Pt pt;
```

and

```
Pt pt = Pt();
```

are equivalent. I suspected that in the second case copy assignment could be called, but as it turns out it isn't the case.

As we ran our little experiment I decided to test a weird bit, that my colleague thought wouldn't even compile:

```
//here the compiler calls a copy constructor and doesn't call the default constructor prior to that
// O_o
Pt pt = pt;
```

Here is a working sample: http://ideone.com/XmJSz7

So, the question is - what goes on in:

```
Pt pt = pt;
```

Comment: "*I suspected that in the second case copy assignment could be called, but as it turns out it isn't the case.*" I suspect you're concluding from the fact that something didn't happen that it couldn't happen. This is invalid reasoning. If I walk across the street without looking both ways and don't get hit by a car, does that mean someone who said I could have gotten hit by a car was incorrect?

Comment: Valid point. Do you suggest that Pt pt = Pt(); could call copy constructor in some case? If so - could you give an example?

Comment: @Vorren - about this `Pt pt = Pt()`, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constructions like `type object = something` call copy constructors, not assignment operators

Having this in mind, here's what happens:

1. `Pt pt =` -> at this point, `Pt` object is created, named `pt` (nothing is initialized at this point)
2. `= pt;` -> at this point, `pt`'s copy constructor is called with argument - itself (`pt`)
3. as `pt` is created BUT not initialized (in `1.`), this is (kinda) valid - `pt`'s copy constructor (in `2.`) will be "properly" executed, taking as right-hand-side argument the already existing and *uninitialized* object `pt` (from `1.` again)

Shortly - this is bad.

It's worth noting, that if the `pt` object is global or static, it *will* be default-initialized at step `1.` - after reaching the `=`.

**EDIT**: regarding the initial "puzzle" `Pt pt = Pt();`, you can see this question: [Is there a difference in C++ between copy initialization and direct initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati) and its accepted answer.
And this one seems interesting, too: [How variable is initialized by default constructor in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513055/how-variable-is-initialized-by-default-constructor-in-c)