# What happens when creating an array of a larger size than initialized C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, null, dimensions

In c++, if you do something like:

```
int array [2][4] = 
{
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5,6,7}
}
```

Is `array [0][3]` null or nonexistent?

Comment: If the `{}` initializer is smaller than the array is defined as, the leftover values are zero initialized.

Answer (score 4):

It is actually [value initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), so it will be `0`. It is similar to if you had

```
int values[5] = {1,2};
```

This would produce the array

```
{1, 2, 0, 0, 0}
```

Here is a thorough description of [zero-, default-, and value-initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializat) if you're interested in the definitions and when each applies.