# Default constructing template parameters to zero if numeric?

Tags: c++, templates, default-value

Consider this example:

```
template<typename T> auto f(T u, T v = T()) { return v; }
int main() {
    double a; float b; int c; long d;   // all possible numerical types here
    auto res1 = f(a);   // is res1 == 0.0?
    auto res2 = f(b);   // is res2 == 0.0?
    auto res3 = f(c);   // is res3 == 0?
    auto res4 = f(d);   // is res4 == 0?
}
```

Is there a guarantee from the Standard that `T()` will default construct a zero numerical value whenever `T` is a numerical type?
If not, how can I make sure that if `T` is numerical, then the default argument for 'v' is `v = 0`, and if `T` is not numerical, then
`v = T()`?

Comment: Yes, it is guaranteed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializat

Comment: @juanchopanza And what if I do `T v;` instead of `auto v = T()`? Will it still be zero if `T` is numeric?

Comment: @juanchopanza I read the question you linked, and follow-up links, but they don't mention templates or function arguments, so I am not sure how the rules apply here. You say it is guaranteed that `v` will be zero. Can you explain why? Maybe write an answer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is *value initialization*. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization