# In C++, what is the difference between X x = X(); type declaration and X x; declaration where X is the class

Tags: c++

In my code I encountered above kind of scenario. Under what circumstances we need to use above style of object creation? Cant we simply create object X x? What thing we have achieved in X x = X(); type declaration?

Comment: Today the answer is "Nothing". However, if you're not elliding copies, then theoretically `X x = X()` is allowed to first construct two instances of `X` by default, and then copy/move assign one to the other.

Comment: @AndyG Even with elision there is still a (slight) difference: `X x = X()` is ill-formed if `X` is not copyable/movable.

Comment: @AndyG It depends on `X`. The difference could be huge. It is default initialization vs. value initialization. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializat.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1051379/27678

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is difference. `X x = X()` requires the copy constructor to be accessible.

For the following class:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(Foo const&) = delete;
    void* ptr;
};
```

This will compile:

```
Foo foo;
```

and this won't:

```
Foo foo = Foo();
```

Furthermore, the first syntax results in default-initialization, so `ptr` has undetermined value, while the second would zero-initialize it to `nullptr` (if the copy constructor wasn't deleted or inaccessible).

The reasonable default is neither of those - uniform initialization syntax (available since C++11):

```
Foo foo{};
```

While less uniform than the name suggests, it leaves your object zero-initialized and is immune to most vexing parse.

Comment: This is good, but you should mention that uniform initialization syntax is a new feature in C++11; many compilers still default to C++03.

Answer (score 0):

You should almost always write either `X x;` or `X x{};`

When `X` is a class type, `X x;` declares `x` as a variable of type `X` and runs the *default constructor* to initialize it.  It could be thought of as shorthand for `X x();`, except that, because of the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), you can't actually *write* `X x();`.

`X x{};` is a new feature in C++11.  It's almost, but not quite, the same as `X x;`.  The important difference is that, with `X x{};`, any data members the default constructor doesn't initialize will be automatically initialized to zero.  With `X x;`, any such members will be left uninitialized.  (With a well-written C++ class, there won't be any members left uninitialized, but `X x{}` is handy for POD structures, such as the ones you might get from system headers geared for plain C.)

`X x = X();` is quite different.  It's formally equivalent to

```
X __temp_0{};
X x(__temp_0);
__temp_0.~X();
```

except for some details of scope and naming that can't be expressed in the language.  It creates an extra temporary variable of type `X` and default-initializes it.  Then it uses X's *copy* constructor to initialize `x` from the temporary, and finally it destroys the temporary (running its destructor).  Whether these two things have the same *effects* depends on what X's constructors and destructor do, and often also on how good your C++ compiler is at optimizing out "abstraction penalties".  And it won't compile at all if `X` doesn't have an accessible, implicit copy constructor.

Comment: This is quite misleading. Depending in `X`, one may leave the objects with uninitialized data members, while the other one doesn't.

Comment: @juanchopanza *When `X` is a class type*, `X x;` and `X x();` always do exactly the same thing.  Whether or not they leave the object with uninitialized data members depends entirely on X's default constructor.

Comment: No, they don't always do exactly the same thing. Unless you have a non-standard definition of "class type", which maybe you could elaborate on to clarify the answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza Any type declared with `struct foo` or `class foo` is what I mean.  It's possible that I am misremembering something, but I really don't think so.  Please give specific references into the C++ standard to back up your contention.

Comment: Right, so that is not entirely correct. `sturct X { int n;};` for example. For automatic storage `x`, `X x;` leaves `x.n` uninitialized, `X x = X();` leaves it zero-initialized (as does `X x{};`)

Comment: @juanchopanza You're talking about `X x;` versus `X x = X();`.  I am talking about `X x;` versus `X x();`.  I should clarify that `X x();` doesn't actually work, because of the most vexing parse, but *if it did work*, it would be exactly the same as `X x;`, *not* `X x = X();`  If you define a constructor `X::X(int) {}` you can observe for yourself that `X x((0))` leaves `x.n` uninitialized.

Comment: You're really making no sense now, sorry. Nobody is comparing a variable declaration to a function declaration here. I refer you back to my first comment.