# Empty value in explicit copy constructor with member initialization list

Tags: c++

Consider this copy constructor:

```
myclass::myclass(const myclass& rhs):
  _a(rhs._a), _b() {
}
```

Assuming _b is defined as:

```
int _b[100];
```

What would `_b` get initialized to? What is the difference between writing `_b()` vs not including `_b` in the list at all?

Comment: Related if not dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_b()` assures that the array `_b` will be [*zero-initialized*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization), i.e. all its elements will be zero.

If you don't include `_b()` in the constructor initializer list, then `_b` will not be initialized (technically it is called [*default-initialized*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization)) and may contain anything. Using it non-initialized causes undefined behaviour.