# What is the meaning of, returning value being a class name followed by a pair of empty parentheses?

Tags: c++, class, syntax, return-value, semantics

I want to know what it means for a function to return a class/structure name followed by parentheses.

For example:

```
struct X{...}; //structure with static members

X g(){ return X(); };
```

I found this in the following link:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Explanation

Comment: Did you mean capital `X`? In that case, it's just creating an anonymous instance of the class by calling the 0-argument constructor.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. I corrected it, thank you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1613341.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
X()
```

calls the default-constructor of struct `X`.

```
return X();
```

means construct a temporary instance of `X` and return it. More specifically, here the temporary is a *[pure r-value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue)* which will be moved to the *[lvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue)* where the function is being called.

that is

```
auto objectX = g();
```

By the above statement, the `objectX`(lvalue) will be initialized by moving the temporary created from the `g()`.

See more about the *value categories* in C++ here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: Does it mean that `X()` returns a value (object) even if it's a constructor that should return nothing by definition? Is it just a special syntax for constructors?