# The usage of class name with the overloaded parentheses

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

In the following example, I understand how boost signal and functor work, however, my question is about how the class name with the overloaded parentheses `HelloWorld()` is used. As `HelloWorld` is a functor, the created object should actually use the `operator()`, not the class (functor) name. What is this practice called and what is its common application?

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <iostream>
struct HelloWorld 
{
  void operator()(int val_) const 
  { 
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << val_  << std::endl;
  } 
};
int main()
{
boost::signals2::signal<void (int)> sig;
HelloWorld hello;
hello(6);
sig.connect(HelloWorld());
sig(5);
}
```

Comment: _"the class name with the overloaded parentheses `HelloWorld()`"_ is a call to the implicitly defined default-constructor of `HelloWorld`. The duplicate should explain the rest.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of "[What is the meaning of, returning value being a class name followed by a pair of empty parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57025272/90527)"