# What are the differences between "T a", "T a()" and "T a=T()" where T is a class?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Let `T` a C++ class.

Is there any difference in behaviour between the following three instructions?

```
T a;
T a();
T a = T();
```

Does the fact that `T` provides an explicit definition for a constructor that takes no parameter change anything with respect to the question?

Follow-up question: what about if `T` provides a definition for a constructor that takes at least one parameter? Will there then be a difference in behaviour between the following two instructions (in this example I assume that the constructor takes exactly one parameter)?

```
T a(my_parameter);
T a = T(my_parameter);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`T a;` performs default initialization.

`T a = T();` performs value initialization.

`T a();` does not declare a variable named `a`. It actually declares a function named `a`, which takes no arguments and whose return type is `T`.

The difference between default initialization and value initialization is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1613341/481267).

Comment: There's also difference in that `T a = T();`  is actually copy-initialisation. Prior to C++17, this would have implied that `T` must be copyable or movable.

Comment: @Brian Bi regarding "T a(); does not declare a variable named a": what about "T a(my_parameter)" when the constructor takes one parameter?

Comment: @Ramanewbie That should work as intended because it cannot be interpreted as a function declaration.