# Differences in variable declarations in C++

Tags: c++, class, variables, declaration

```
Class A 
{
};
```

What is the difference between `A a` , `A* a` and `A* a = new A()`.

Comment: closed as "not a real question". The given code isn't C++.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
A a;
```

Creates an instance of an A that lives on the stack using the default constructor.

```
A *a;
```

Is simply a *uninitialized* pointer to an A.  It doesn't actually point to an A object at this point, but could.  An initialized pointer (in this case, set to NULL) would look like so:

```
A *a = 0;
```

The difference here is that a null pointer does not point to any object while an uninitialized pointer might point anywhere.  Initializing your pointers is a good practice to get into lest you find yourself wondering why your program is blowing up or yielding incorrect results.

Similarly, you don't want to attempt to *dereference* either a NULL pointer or an uninitialized pointer.  But you can test the NULL pointer.  Testing an uninitialized pointer yields undetermined and erroneous results.  It may in fact be != 0 but certainly doesn't point anywhere you intend it to point.  Make sure you **initialize** your pointers before testing them and **test** them before you attempt to dereference them.

```
A a = new A();
```

should be written as

```
A *a = new A();
```

and that creates a new A object that was allocated on the heap.  The A object was created using the *default* constructor.

Where a default constructor is not explicitly written for a class, the compiler will implicitly create one though I don't believe the standard does not specify the state of data members for the object implicitly instantiated.  For a discussion about implicit default constructors, see Martin York's response to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563221/is-there-an-implicit-default-constructor-in-c).

Comment: It's probably worth noting that `A a` calls the default constructor too, if you're going to mention that about the heap-allocated version.

Comment: Its also worth noting that `A *a;` creates an uninitialized pointer.  The only thing that you can do with it is assign a value to it (meaning, no comparisons or other uses).  It might be worth adding a fourth example, `A *a = 0`, in which case `a` can be used in comparisons.

Comment: The last statement is incorect. The object `A()` is created with *value-initialization*. It doesn't use any contructors of `A` (in this case). Expression `A()` will use the default contructor only when it is explicitly declared by user. Otherwise, the initialization proceeds without using the constructor.

Comment: @AndreyT - Agreed - there will be an implicit construction done by the compiler if there isn't a default constructor explicitly defined for the class.  The assumption I made here was that there was one - despite the fact that OP's class is empty - because there typically is one defined.  The distinction is a good one to make and I thank you for pointing that out.  I'll add a note to the answer.

Comment: Consider: `struct A { ~A() { } int const a; };`. Then `new A()` is perfectly valid (and initializes `a` to zero). But if it would use the default constructor like in `A a;` or `new A` it would be ill-formed (because of the `const` member). So it makes a big difference whether the default constructor is used or not.

Answer (score 8):

`A a` declares an instance of `A` named `a`

`A *a` declares a pointer to a `A` class

`A *a = new A()` allocates space for `a` on the heap and calls the proper constructor (if no constructor is specified, it performs default initialization).

For further information about the last form see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_%28C%2B%2B%29

Comment: Although the last one should have been `A* a = ...`

Comment: The last one doesn't just allocate space for `a` on the heap. It also initializes the `A` object, and declares a pointer to it.

Comment: @Jalf, how about A a, where does it allcate memory . i can see constructor gets implicitly called when we put A a .

Comment: @Sachin: wherever it is declared. If a class contains a member declared in this way, it increases the class object's size enough to hold an additional `A`. If it is declared in a function, it is put on the call stack.

Comment: @jalf, Does it mean unless I use new the memory gets allocated on stack rather than on heap.

Comment: Same error as in the other answer. `A()` calls the contructor only when it is explicitly declared by user. Otherwise, it perform *value-initialization*, which does not involve the constructor of `A`.