# Why is operator= and copy-constructor NOT implicitly generated in this case?

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors, constants, copy-constructor

I have a struct like this:

```
/* Renderable definition */
    struct Renderable
    {
        Renderable(VertexBufferPtr vertexBuffer, const Mat4& wvpMatrix, const Mat4& worldMatrix, const Vec4& diffuseColor, const float specularFactor) : 
                    mVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer), mTransform(wvpMatrix, worldMatrix), mMaterial(diffuseColor, specularFactor)
        {
        }

        /* Transform definition */
        struct Transform
        {
            Transform(const Mat4& wvpMatrix, const Mat4& worldMatrix) : mWVPMatrix(wvpMatrix), mWorldMatrix(worldMatrix)
            {
            }

            const Mat4 mWVPMatrix;
            const Mat4 mWorldMatrix; 
        };

        /* Material definition */
        struct Material
        {
            Material(const Vec4& diffuseColor, const float specularFactor) : mDiffuseColor(diffuseColor), mSpecularFactor(specularFactor)
            {
            }

            const Vec4 mDiffuseColor;
            const float mSpecularFactor;
        };


        const VertexBufferPtr mVertexBuffer;
        const Transform mTransform;
        const Material mMaterial;
    };

    /* RenderQueue definition */
    typedef std::vector<Renderable> RenderQueue;
```

When I try to use it in my code like this;

```
RenderQueue CreateRenderQueue(const Scene* scene);

....

RenderQueue renderQueue(CreateRenderQueue(activeScene));
```

I get the follow compile error:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(2514): error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'Renderable'
```

After some digging I came to realise it was because I had not defined the assignment operator and the copy-constructor. I then did so, and voilah! it compiled...

....My question is however, why is the assignment operator and the copy constructor NOT implicitly generated by the compiler? (vs2010) I did not define them, so surely they would be generated?

Thanks

Comment: What is `VertexBufferPtr`?  Is it copyable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have constant class member objects, so you cannot assign those. A copy constructor should be generated, though.

Comment: You just saved my day, never thought about this before.

Answer (score 0):

See [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563221/is-there-an-implicit-default-constructor-in-c), which states the conditions for an implicit default constructor (emphasis mine):

> If you do not define *a constructor*, the compiler will define a default constructor for you

You defined a constructor, hence the implicit default one is not available anymore, it's up to you to define one.

In fact, a few lines below the same answer gives the same rule for all of the essential methods of classes:

> If no destructor/copy Constructor/Assignment operator is defined the compiler builds one of those for you