# Should we need to provide a default constructor in c++ if we use a parameter constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, default-constructor

Should we need to provide a default constructor in c++ if we use a parameter constructor?
my code is like this.

```
ReadConfigParams::ReadConfigParams(char *file)
```

Comment: If your class needs ones, yes. If not, no.

Comment: Also, use std::string.

Comment: @user3159253: `std::vector` does not require its elements to be default constructible.

Comment: @Ben, perhaps the constructor intends to open a file, and `ifstream::open` expects `char *` ..:)

Comment: @Matt McNabb This has been fixed in c++11, and you can always use `std::string::c_str()` to convert to a zero-terminated `const char *`. (Also, use const correctness) ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want a client of ReadConfigParams class should instantiate an object of this class.

If the class ReadConfigParams always requires a file name (as in most of the cases), you should NOT define a default constructor because it doesn't make sense to instantiate ReadConfigParams without an associated file. This will effectively prevent a client from creating an object of this class without a given file name.

But if the class ReadConfigParams can provide some default configuration values then you SHOULD define a default constructor. This will enable a client of this class to instantiate and hence access the default values without a file reading operation.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if you don't declare a default constructor for a class, the compiler supplies one for you.

However, note that, **the default constructor will only be created by the compiler if you provide no constructor whatsoever**. For your example, you have provided one constructor that takes one argument, the compiler will then **NOT** create the default constructor for you.

Example-1:

```
class A
{
};

int main() 
{
    A a; // OK, as the compiler creates one for you
}
```

Example-2:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int){}
};

int main() 
{
    A a; // NOT OK, error: no appropriate default constructor available!
}
```

Example-3:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){}
    A(int){}
};

int main() 
{
    A a; // OK, as you explicitly provide one default constructor
}
```

Also, according to "C++11 – ISO-IEC 14882-2011" §8.5/6:

> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type `T`, `T` shall be a class type with a user-provided default constructor.

You can check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/563221/2589776) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

**Question** Should we need to provide a default constructor in c++ if we use a parameter constructor?

**Answer** It depends.

If you wish to create an array of objects, you must provide a default constructor.

```
ReadConfigParams array[10];
```

won't work if you have a don't have a default constructor. Similarly, you can't allocate an array of object using `operator new`.

```
ReadConfigParams* arrayPtr = new ReadConfigParams[10];
```

won't work either.

If you don't have any need for creating arrays, in stack or from heap, not providing a default constructor is fine.