# Struct default constructor: will it initialize my members with default vaues i.e. 'zeros'

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, language-lawyer

I am learning about constructors and I need a clarification. I can build a struct as follows without specifying a constructor:

```
 struct MyStruct {
 int member;
 }
```

When I make an object of this struct the generated default constructor will not initialize `member` to a default vlaue unless explicitly stated in a user defined constructor, correct? So that this:

```
MyStruct object;
cout<<object.member<<endl;
```

will output some random value depending on what is stored in that memory address at runtime, correct?

My final question is, If I do not explicitly declare and define a constructor will the generated constructor initialize `member` when I create an object of `MyStruct` or is `member` left uninitialized?

Comment: Please see [This Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563221/is-there-an-implicit-default-constructor-in-c)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417065/does-the-default-constructor-initialize-built-in-types

Comment: _"A, right? Yeah, A. Now, my final question is: A?"_ What?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, built-in types are not initialized by the compiler generated constructor.

The compiler generated constructor is exactly the same as:

```
MyStruct() {}
```

Accessing `MyStruct.member` then leads to undefined behaviour. You should explicitly initialize `member`:

```
MyStruct() : member(0) {}
```

Comment: In addition, I suggest using a C++ static analysis tool, such as CppCheck to find out errors/mistakes like this one. It's very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This definitely cleared things up.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you explicitly use a "in class initializer" - like `int member = 0;` *or* add a constructor that initializes the member, then its value will be *undefined*.

It will *not* (necessarily) be whatever is stored at the memory address at runtime. It is *undefined*; meaning you cannot use it reliably and *if* you do, your compiler may take advantage of the fact that you are then invoking "undefined behaviour" and may optimize your program based on that fact - something you most certainly do not want.

Always initialize your variables before use.